# Naming after bad people

Tags: names, historical-figures, evil-resha, yishmael

Why have there been famous(ly righteous) [Jewish people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi%5FYishmael) named after [Yishma'el](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yishmael), who, [Chaza"l](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chazal) tell us, was evil and an enemy of Jews? Has anything similar happened with Esav? Korach? Others?

Comment: Qorah is a popular Teimoni family name. in Kefayet al-abiddin (HaMaspik) R. Avraham writes that Qorah was a great person who erred.

Comment: This question would be improved if you cite a reason why you think that it is forbidden to name after the wicked.

Comment: @mevaqesh This is not a question of _halacha_. I think such a citation would be interesting, and indeed would be a useful piece of a good answer. But the question is based on the premises that a) parents usually wish well on their children, b) conferring of names is a very common avenue for parents to express those wishes, c) comparison to evil people is not a well wish.

Comment: Well unless the considerations for the naming are rooted in some halakhic or otherwise Jewish consideration, then the question seems to be about Jews not Judaism, and hence, off-topic.

Comment: @mevaqesh Please vote to close. I do not wish to wade into this discussion at the moment. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/262/3

Comment: I don't think this is related to that conversation. Would you mind if at a later date I edit in information to improve the question?

Answer (score 22):

According to at least one major tradition, Yishma'el repented later in his life. [Gen. 25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible%5Fcdo/aid/8220/showrashi/true):9 says that after [Avraham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham) died, "[Yitzchak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac) and Yishmael his sons buried him ..." According to *[Genesis Rabba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis%5FRabba)* as quoted by [Rashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) there, the order indicates that Yishma'el repented, as he recognized the precedence due his younger but covenentally endowed brother.

For some reason, despite the great [R' Yishma'el](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi%5FYishmael) being so named, the practice of using the name Yishma'el [seems](http://www.cross-currents.com/archives/2004/12/08/conversions-and-hebrew-names/) to have [fallen](http://www.cross-currents.com/archives/2004/12/15/bullseye/) out of widespread Jewish practice. This might have to do with more recent conflicts with Muslim nations and groups.

I'm not aware of famous Jews being named ['Esav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esau) or [Korach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B3rach), but then, there's no indication that either of them repented.

#### Bonus material:

My high school principal told us a cute thing about R' Yishm'ael and his namesake. I don't remember all of it, but I'll repeat what I can reconstruct. R' Yishma'el compiled [13 Rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraita%5Fof%5FRabbi%5FIshmael) to be used for inferring laws from the words of the Torah. The fourth and fifth of these are inverse of each other:

4) Kelal Uperat / General then Specific - If a verse contains a general rule followed by a specific example, the general rule is taken to only apply to the case described by the example.

5) Perat Ukelal / Specific then General - If a verse describes examples followed by a general rule, the rule is taken to apply in general.

These two types of verses look the same except for the order of the elements. One might wonder whether we can really take into account the order of elements in this way. According to R' Yishma'el's tradition, we can and do, at least when the elements are within a single verse.

And this works well for R' Yishma'el himself, since the appropriateness of his name is dependent on the fact that his namesake repented, which we derive based on the ordering within a verse of his brother's name and his own. If the order wasn't significant, we couldn't make such an inference.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68756/discussion-on-answer-by-isaac-moses-naming-after-bad-people).

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, we don't name after bad people, unless the name means something nice.  (This is on a Rabbi Frand tape.)  There are plenty of "Avshalom"s out there today -- while the Biblical Avshalom who committed treason against his father King David wasn't a nice guy, the name -- "father (cause) of peace" is nice.

Contrast with a name like "Do'eg", which is both a Biblical baddie, and means "worry."

Comment: Just curious if you can explain why "Nimrod" has become a common Israeli name?   He was not a savory Biblical character and I can't identify a positive name translation either.

Comment: From what I've heard, that one might actually be an intentional finger in the eye of the religious crowd. Nimrod was a strong leader who rebelled against God. I don't think you find many religious Israelis naming their kids that.

Comment: Indeed. I used to have a Hebrew book called פסוק לי שמך, which contained lists of names and the associated pesukim (for reciting at the end of Shemoneh Esreh). The author included the names Nimrod and Goliath in their respective places, but with a footnote referring to the back of the book, where he reproduced some correspondence he had with R' Shlomo Yosef Zevin on this subject. The point made there was exactly that: these are not names that _should_ be used; but post facto, if someone does bear these names, the appropriate verses need to be provided.

Comment: Aaron, there is one pirush in the mikraos gedolos associates Nimrod's name with a positive idea.

אבן עזרא על בראשית פרק י פסוק ט 
(ט) וטעם לפני ה' - שהי' בונה מזבחות ומעלה אותם החיות עולה לשם וזו דרך הפשט. והדרש דרך אחרת:
and in the Hizkuni:

חזקוני על בראשית פרק י פסוק ט 
(ט) גבר ציד לפני ה' - בעולם, וכן עיר גדולה לאלקים בכל עולמו של הקב"ה לא היתה עיר גדולה כמוה. ד"א לפני ה' ע"פ הדבור ... שלפני ה' הוא ע"פ הדיבור אף כאן פירש ממרום נגזר על נמרוד שתצלח רוח גבורה עליו ויתפוש נצחו בכל אשר ילך.

Comment: and therfore...

חזקוני על בראשית פרק י פסוק ט 
על כן יאמר כנמרד - על כן כל אדם אשר יריק את חניכיו לחנכו לתפוש חרב מברכו ברכה זו כנמרוד שגזר עליו הקב"ה להיות גבור ציד לצוד ציד שלא ישמט מידו חיה רעה דוב וחזיר יער וארי, כן תצלח בחרב זו שאני חוגרך ותתפוש נצחון בכל אשר תלך.

Comment: @Isaac-Moses: An Isreali told me that a while ago (perhaps in the 70s), the Rabbis ruled that one should not call their sons Nimrod. This was apparently in response to the increasing popularity of the name. This Israeli told me that because of this he has three friends whose secular parents deliberately named them Nimrod.

Comment: @AaronGreenberg http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/446/arbaa-mi-yodeya/35007#35007

Comment: @Yahu I think it is somewhat unlikely the typical Chiloni family are familiar with this פירוש in the חיזקוני  haha

Comment: @Alex I'm quite sure R' Chaim Kanievsky would ask these Nimrods to change their names...

Comment: It makes me wonder if Doeg's name really was that or they changed it when writing him into the Tanach, similar to the way that Chazal call Bar Kochba "Bar Koziba" when that wasn't his real name, to show readers they did not approve of him or his actions.

Answer (score 7):

I think the Chida addresses these issues as well, in (appropriately enough) "Shem haGedolim." It is also interesting that, as far as I know, none of the rabbis in the Mishna/Talmud are named Moshe. In the larger world, of course names go in and out of style, but this is even more so in the Jewish world, where we have strong traditions of naming after relatives (deceased or living, according to your minhagim), so once you hit a critical mass of tzaddikim with a certain name, it can become extremely popular. Similarly, once a name disappears from the population at large, it can be very difficult to revive.

Comment: Jeremy- Thanks for bringing that book to my attention. It looks very interesting. Where in it is this topic discussed?

Comment: sorry--it's been a long time and I don't personally have a copy.
try hebrewbooks.org

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, R' HID"A writes about these names (e.g. Avraham, Yizhaq, \`Esaw, Eli\`ezer, Yishma`\el) in Shem HaGedolim in a commentary following the name "Mar Rav Avraham Ga'on" ([pp. 8-9 here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/shemhagdolim/shemhagdolim04.pdf)). Thank you to R' Uri Sherqi for pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

Regarding using a wicked person's name, the [Ri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Samuel) seems to hold that it is permissible to give someone the same name as a wicked person, so long as that name historically did not uniquely belong to wicked people or to a single wicked person.

---

The gemara ([*Shabbos* 12b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=12b&format=text)) cites a teaching in the name of Shevna Ish Yerushalayim. *Tosafos* (ad loc.) write:

> Rabbeinu Tam's version does not include the name "Shevna", for Shevna<sup>1</sup> was wicked,<sup>2</sup> and we do not bring citations in the name of the wicked,<sup>3</sup> for "the name of the wicked should rot" ([*Mishlei* 10:7](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2810.htm#7)), as it says in chapter *Amar Lahem HaM'munah* ([*Yoma* 38b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=38b&format=text)). He rather emends it to read "Shachna", which is also the name of a person, as it says in *Sotah* ([21a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=21&format=text)), "rather like Shachna brother of Hillel".<sup>4</sup>
>
> And it appears to the Ri that the correct version is in fact "Shevna", for if there is one wicked person named Avraham, should we avoid calling another person by that name?<sup>5</sup> And in reality, there were two people named Shevna, as is demonstrable from *Isaiah*, as it is written, "Shevna who is in charge of the house..." ([22:15](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1022.htm#15)), and it is written, "and I will call to my servant, to Elyakim... and I will give over your rule to his hand" (22:20-21), and it is written after this, "And Elyakim, who is in charge of the house, and Shevna the scribe came to him..." ([36:22](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1036.htm#22)),<sup>6</sup> implying that the Shevna who was in charge of the house already died, and Elyakim was in his place, and Shevna the scribe was someone else.<sup>7</sup>

Possibly, according to the Ri, a name is acceptable if it is not unique to a single wicked person, even if multiple wicked people shared that name.

However, the Ri might not consider "Shevna the scribe" to have been wicked. This is supported by *Tosafos*' characterization of the "יש מפרשים" ([*Yoma* 38b, s.v. *d'lo maskei bishmaihu*](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=38b&format=text)) as considering Shevna the scribe to be righteous. If so, it is possible that the Ri would consider a name that was known only to be given to wicked people to be unacceptable.

The principle that is the subject of disagreement between Rabbeinu Tam and the Ri seems to apply to naming people, as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>*Isaiah* [36:3, 11, 22](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1036.htm); [37:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1037.htm)</sub>

<sup>2</sup>  <sub>[*Sanhedrin* 26a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=26&format=text)</sub>

<sup>3</sup>  <sub>See Rashi on *Yoma* 38b (s.v. דלא מסקי בשמייהו), who understands this expression to mean that fathers would not name their sons after wicked people</sub>

<sup>4</sup>  <sub>Interestingly, the prevalent printed version of *Sotah* names Hillel's brother as Shevna. *Tosafos* on *Yoma* (38b) might be read to indicate that Rabbeinu Tam was also responsible for the emendation of "Shevna" to "Shachna" in *Sotah* (ibid.)</sub>

<sup>5</sup>  <sub>Rhetorical question</sub>

<sup>6</sup>  <sub>The verse here is paraphrased and slightly different than the text in *Isaiah*</sub>

<sup>7</sup>  <sub>*Tosafos* elsewhere ([*K'suvos* 104b, s.v. *sh'nei*](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=104b&format=text); *Yoma* 38b, s.v. *d'lo maskei bishmaihu*) argue that Shevna is the same person in both instances and bring evidence for this from *Sanhedrin* 26a</sub>

Comment: +1 - I assume this is not meant to explain R' Yishma'el, as (unless you accept the other answers here) there was just the evil one, and no precedent of a good one for the original R' Yishma'el to use.

Comment: @YEZ Correct, this was just meant to supplement other answers by mentioning a general principle discussed in Tosafos. Plus, as mentioned in [Isaac Moses' answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/74/), Yishmael did *t'shuva*.

Answer (score 1):

The name Korach (which is the name of one of Eisav's children) is stated as one of the reasons Korach (the one who rebelled againt Moshe) did what he did. Therefore, naming a child after him would definitely be a bad idea.

Comment: Who says this reason?