# Arba'a - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After Shabbat, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Previous: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/431/shelosha-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/474/chamisha-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Four are the [sheep](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0221.htm) you give back for stealing and slaughtering/selling one.  Bah!

Four is the minimum number of children (two boys, two girls) at which point [Rabbi Yehuda Herzl Henkin](http://www.yoatzot.org/article.php?id=169) and [Rabbi Herschel Shachter](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/725233/Rabbi_Hershel_Schachter/Responding_to_the_current_challenges_of_the_Family_and_Community_in_crisis) would allow a couple to practice contraception indefinitely.

Comment: Way to expose important positions in an important area of Halacha. Of course people should make sure to consult their own Rabbi before acting on this information.

Answer (score 13):

The number of columns (turim) of stones on the Choshen Mishpat. ([Exodus 28:17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0228.htm#17))

Ironically enough, Choshen Mishpat is one of the Arba'a Turim. Which brings another answer: the number of sections in the Arba'a Turim and Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: Ch"M is also the fourth Tur. +1 (I'd +4 if I could).

Answer (score 13):

Four men died without sins:

Binyamin, 
Amram, 
Yishai, 
Kil'av.

Comment: Shabbos 55b is the source.

Answer (score 12):

... levels on which to understand the Torah:
פשט- plain meaning, 
רמז- hints, 
דרש- exegesis, 
סוד- secret, hidden, underlying essential meaning

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14750/759

Answer (score 11):

the most popular number during the Passover Sedar.
Four questions.
Four sons.
Four cups of wine.

Answer (score 11):

I know we all like to provide out-of-the-box answers, but I'm disappointed that I have to be the one to give this answer, and nearly two years after the question was asked - [4 Imahoth (Matriarchs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriarchs#Matriarchs).

Answer (score 10):

Four sons before Leah gave praise/thanks to Hashem (Yehuda).
Four are the number of wives (mates) that Yaakov had.
Twelve divided by Four equals Three sons per wife. Thus when Yehuda was born, Leah realized she got even more than her "fair share" and gave a special thanks.

Answer (score 10):

We take 4 Minim on Succos: Lulav, Esrog, Hadas, Arava ([Leviticus 23:40](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0323.htm#40))

Answer (score 10):

4 holy cities, Yerushalayim, Chevron, Teveria, Tzefas

Comment: A source would be great here.

Comment: @SethJ: Although I do not know the original source for this - [here you can see](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4618&st=&pgnum=588&hilite=) the Lubavitcher Rabbi Zatzal discussing this concept.

Answer (score 10):

4 shades of white that constitute tzara'at. (Snow, plaster, eggshell and wool)

([Negaim 1:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%90))

Answer (score 10):

BS"D

Four rivers emgered out of Gan Edhen
 ["וְנָהָר יֹצֵא מֵעֵדֶן, לְהַשְׁקוֹת אֶת-הַגָּן; וּמִשָּׁם, יִפָּרֵד, וְהָיָה, לְאַרְבָּעָה רָאשִׁים"](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0102.htm#10)

Four kingdoms allied and won the first great war 
[" אֵת כְּדָרְלָעֹמֶר מֶלֶךְ עֵילָם, וְתִדְעָל מֶלֶךְ גּוֹיִם, וְאַמְרָפֶל מֶלֶךְ שִׁנְעָר, וְאַרְיוֹךְ מֶלֶךְ אֶלָּסָר--אַרְבָּעָה מְלָכִים, אֶת-הַחֲמִשָּׁה."](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0114.htm#9)

Four corners require SiSith "[גְּדִלִים, תַּעֲשֶׂה-לָּךְ, עַל-אַרְבַּע כַּנְפוֹת כְּסוּתְךָ, אֲשֶׁר תְּכַסֶּה-בָּהּ"](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0522.htm#12)

Answer (score 9):

Four couples buried in Mi'aras HaMachpeilah in Kiryas Arba Hi Hevron.

Answer (score 9):

Four are the [cubits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubit) of:

- [Separation](http://www.torah.org/learning/rambam/kriatshema/ks3.6.html)
- A real [room](http://koltorah.org/ravj/Do_Walk_In_Closets_and_Porches_Require_a_Mezuzah_2.html)
- [Transportation](http://www.headcoverings-by-devorah.com/CarryingOnShabbat.html) as creation
- Divine residence in [exile](http://www.ou.org/index.php/shabbat_shalom/article/33745/)

Comment: And four are the handbreadths of a "private space."
http://www.torah.org/learning/halacha/classes/class447.html

(If you just see the phrase "Dalet al dalet", you don't know if it's cubits or handbreadths; the former is "arba al arba [amot]", the latter "arba'a al arba'a [tefachim]"

Answer (score 9):

Four are the levels of the [separative trop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantillation#The_syntactical_function).

Answer (score 9):

The kabbalistic worlds: atzilut, yetzira, beriya, and asiyah.

Comment: Can you please provide a source?

Comment: What about Adam Kadmon?

Answer (score 8):

[Arba'a Avos Nezikin](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=2&format=pdf), [Arba'a Rashei Shanim Hem](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=2&format=pdf)...

Answer (score 8):

... are the earthly elemental states according to ancient philosophy and Kabbalah:

Earth (solid), Air (gas), Fire (plasma), and Water (liquid)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element,

Midrash Rabba, Bamidbar 14,12, טבעים,

Zohar I, 27a,

http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/zdm/zdm021.htm

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22542

Answer (score 8):

4 animals mentioned in the Torah that have only one Siman of Tahara and are thus Non-Kosher. ([Leviticus 11:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0311.htm#4), [Deuteronomy 14:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0514.htm#7))

Answer (score 8):

We Daven four Amidos (colloquially known as Shemonah Esreis) on Shabbos, Yom Tov, and Rosh Chodesh

Answer (score 8):

There are four types of death by a Beis Din - Stoning, Burning, Beheading and Strangulation. ([Sanhedrin 49b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=49b&format=pdf))

They carried out the four death sentences against him (Bilaam). - Sanhedrin 106b

Answer (score 8):

Starting from the Shabbos before Rosh Chodesh Adar - or Adar2 in a leap year - we read what is known as the Daled Parshiyos - 4 special readings for the Maftir. Parshas Shekalim, Parshas Zachor, Parshas Parah, and Parshas HaChodesh.

Answer (score 7):

Four are the levels of tum'ah applicable to non-sacred foods.

Answer (score 6):

There are four shomerim - שומר חינם, שואל, נושא שכר, ושוכר. ([Bava Metzia 93a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=93&format=pdf))

Answer (score 6):

Pirkei Avos Ch. 5:

4 times when pestilence increases - 4th, 7th, and year after shemitta, and after sukkos (12)

4 types of people - what's mine is mine etc... (13)

4 types of mindsets - angers easily cools off easily, angers slowly cools off slowly, angers slowly cools off easily, angers easily cools off slowly (14)

4 types of students - Understand quickly and forgets quickly, understands with difficulty and forgets with difficulty, understands quickly and forgets with difficulty, understands with difficulty and forgets quickly (15)

4 types of tzeddaka givers - gives himself and wants others to give etc... (16)

4 types of people who go to the Beis Medrash - goes and doesn't study, studies and doesn't go, goes and studies, doesn't go and doesn't study (17)

4 types of people who sit before chachamim - sponge, funnel, strainer, sieve (18)

Answer (score 6):

four letter of the tetragrammaton Y-H-V-H which is ultimately the source of most things four you will find in the torah. see shaarei kedusha.

Comment: The Tetragrammaton does not consist of those ENGLISH letters.

Answer (score 6):

Four are the [fasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta'anit) for the Mikdash.

(Hat-tip: my daughter)

Answer (score 5):

Moshiach has four names. Menachem, Shilo, Yinon, and Chanina which spells Moshiach

Comment: -1 Eicha Rabbah lists "Tzemach" too.

Comment: Source?_________

Comment: @DoubleAA: [Eichah Rabbah 1:57](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14384&pgnum=383). Though it then points out that צמח and מנחם count as the same thing because they have the same gematria.

Comment: @HodofHod I don't know that it's -1 worthy. These are clearly all homiletic: if someone came and had all the rambam's characteristics of Mashiach and did all the things etc. but his name was Bob, I would still accept him as Mashiach. My point is there is no wrong answer for the name of Mashiach.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't disagree, but ultimately, if you want to count the names of Moshiach, and you leave out one, then you end up with the wrong number. If he'd said "4 are the names listed in <source>" then I'd agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

Four expressions of redemption from Egypt.

Answer (score 5):

On Rosh Chodesh we have four Aliyos to the Torah.

Comment: Also Chol HaMoed.

Answer (score 5):

Four is the number of cities King Nimrod sacrificed when he abandoned the cause of the Tower of Babel: Babel, Erech, Achad, and Kaleh.

Four is also the number of cities he was able to build as a reward once he got to Ashur: Ninveh, Rehoboth Ir, Kalah, and the great city, Resen.

(Gen 10:10-12, Targum Pseudo Jonathan ibid)

Answer (score 4):

There are four verses in Megillas Esther which the listeners read out loud.

Comment: Machzor Vitri says this is אינו חובה ואינו מנהג אלא שמחת תינוקות

Answer (score 4):

Four is number of angels, faces, wings and hands (on each angel) of [Yechzkiel's vision](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16099#v=6)

Answer (score 3):

Four are the cardinal directions:

- East/Qedem (Shemot 27:13)
- South/Negev (Bereshit 24:62)
- North/Tzafon (Yeshayahu 14:13)
- West/Yam (Bemidbar 34:60)

Answer (score 3):

Four are the corners of the Mizbeahh.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 which are subdivided into FOUR ways to move something from a private domain to a public domain on Shabbos (Shabbos Mishna 1:1)

Comment: And two which are four remembrances of tumah, two which are four shevuos, and two which are four types of tzara'as (Shevuos 1:1, which also brings Yetzi'os HaShabbos).

Answer (score 3):

4 exiles: בבל, פרס ומדי, יון. אדום.

These correspond to the letters of the word גשנה, which stands for גוף שכל נפש הכל.
גוף corresponds to גלות פרס ומדי.
שכל corresponds to גלות יון.
נפש corresponds to גלות בבל.
הכל corresponds to גלות אדום.

This is also connected to the 4 sides of the דריידל.

There are 4 sons of יבן (see 1 Chronicles 1:7 and Genesis 9:4)
There are 4 sons of חם (see 1 Chronicles 1:8 and Genesis 9:6)
There are 4 sons of ארם (see Genesis 9:23)
There are 4 sons of ראואל (see 1 Chronicles 1:37)
There are 4 sons of ראומה (see Genesis 22:24)

Comment: What about Golus Yishmo'eil?

Answer (score 3):

There are four tzitzit on tallit.

Answer (score 3):

[Sotah 42b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.42b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - In reward for the four tears Orpah shed over her mother-in-law Naomi, she merited to bear four mighty men (Saph, Madon, Golyas & Yishbi Benov)

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 types of creations: Domem (like stones), Tsomeach (plants), Chai (animals), and Medaber (humans).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_chain_of_being

Answer (score 2):

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/34936/

There are four things called “two which are four,” all of which are found in the first Mishnah of Shevuos. The below sources indicate other places where the teachings appear.

- Carrying on Shabbos (Shabbos 1:1)
- Colors of Tzara’as (Negaim 1:1)
- Types of Shevuos (Shevuos 3:1)
- Realizations of one’s status of tumah (...Nope, this one doesn’t show up elsewhere.)

Answer (score 2):

**4**- are the number of things required for a "תנאי" --*halachik* stipulation/ condition-- to be considered valid (see **Rambam**, [Hilchos Ishus 6:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Marriage.6.1-2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

1) **שיהיה כפול** - The stipulation must be "twofold," with both a positive and negative statement

- Example: if you do x then we're married, and if you don't do x then we're not married (see [Kiddushin 61a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.61a.9?lang=bi))

2) **שיהיה הן שלו קודם ללאו** -  The positive stipulation must be stated before the negative stipulation

- Ex: see example used in #1 (see [Gittin 75b](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.75b.3-8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he))

3) **שיהיה התנאי קודם למעשה** - the stipulation must be mentioned before the action

- Example: "I'll give you $100 if you climb Mount Everest" would be invalid, since the stipulation precedes the action (see [Bava Metzia 94a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.94a.3?lang=bi))

4) **שיהיה התנאי דבר שאפשר לקיימו** - the stipulation made must be possible for one to fulfill

- Example: stating "I'll do this on condition you go all the way to the heavens" is obviously not possible and would thus be in valid (see [Bava Metzia 94a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.94a.14?lang=bi))

Answer (score 2):

Four categories of Korbanos, according to the Rambam (Maaseh Korbonos 1:2)

> וכל הקרבנות בין של צבור בין של יחיד ארבעה מינין: עולה וחטאת ואשם
> ושלמים
>
> All Korbanos - both communal and personal - are of four primary categories - *Olah, Chatas, Asham* and *Shelamim*.

Answer (score 1):

There are four people called Chanoch in the Torah. Chanoch son of Kayin (Bereishis 4:17), Chanoch son of Yered (Bereishis 5:18), Chanoch son of Midyan (Bereishis 25:4), and Chanoch son of Re'uvein (Bereishis 46:9). As you can see, all four of these are found in Seifer Bereishis.

Answer (score 1):

Four...

-...commoners have no share in the World to Come: Balaam, Doeg, Ahithophel and Gehazi. (Sanhedrin 90a)

- ...vessels Hashem knocked and found to be full of urine (worthless): Adam, Cain, Balaam, and Hezekiah. (Breshis Rabbah 19:11)
- Biblical figures who vowed, 2 incurred loss (Yaakov and Jephtah) and the other 2 profitted (Hannah and Klal Israel) - Bereshit Rabbah 70:4

Answer (score 1):

4 sons referenced in the Haggadah: חכם, רשע, תם and שאינו יודע לשאול.

4 relationships with Hashem referenced in ידיד נפש: master-servant, romantic love, father-son, friendship.

4 types of worshippers referenced at the end of פסוקי דזמרה of Shabbos: ישרים, צדיקים, חסידים and קדושים.

Comment: 4 sons was mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

[*Mishna*, *K'resos* 2:1](//www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Keritot.2.1):

> Four people are wanting purification, and four offer a sacrifice for an intentional sin….

Answer (score 0):

Four is the lowest age of chinuch for standard mitzvos.

Comment: Can you cite a source?

Answer (score 0):

Four are the number of ages at which Chazal recommend that one should get married, each one more optimal than the next:

Fourteen, Sixteen, Eighteen and Twenty.

Comment: A citation would be great here.

Answer (score 0):

I know four, the maximum number of times Rasha'im get reincarnated! Based on Amos 1:3 (see Assarah Perakim L'Ramchal 10:3)

Answer (score 0):

There are four corners of the world, that man was created from [(Yalkut Shimoni)](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.13.2?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Answer (score -1):

Four is the number of the Chief-Archangels before the Divine Throne: Mikha'el, Rafa'el, Gavri'el and Uri'el.

In the Kabbalah, these Chief-Princes are set over the Four Elements: Mikha'el over Fire, Rafa'el over Air, Gavri'el over Water, and Uri'el over Earth.

Again they are set over the Four Seasons:  Mikha'el over Summer, Rafa'el over Spring, Gavri'el over Winter, and Uri'el over Autumn.

Again they are also set over the Four types of Creatures: Mikha'el over Walking, Rafa'el over Flying, Gavri'el over Swimming, and Uri'el over Creeping.

These Four Great Malakhim also hold power and subjugation over the Four Demon Kings (who I will not name here).

These Holy Ones additionally are set over the Four Cardinal Directions: Mikha'el in the South, Rafa'el in the East, Gavri'el in the West, and Uri'el in the North.

Concerning the four letters of the Ineffable Name: Rafa'el connects to Yod, Mikha'el to Hei, Gavri'el to Vav, and Uri'el to Hei.

The name of the Great Archangel Rafa'el is also composed of four letters, over Wednesday the Fourth Day he is set.

The Great Archangel Mikha'el is also set over the Fourth Heaven: Ma'on. This is where the Heavenly Yerushalayim and Beit Ha'Miqdash reside.

The Holy One, blessed be he, also set these Heavenly Hosts over certain planets of our Galaxy: Mikha'el over the Sun and Mercury, Rafa'el over Mercury and the Sun, Gavri'el over the Moon and Stars, Uri'el over the Earth and Venus. (I should note that the other Archangel's also have planetary associations: Tzadqi'el over Jupiter, Caftsi'el over Saturn, Chamu'el and S..ama..el over Mars, Hani'el over Venus, Razi'el over the Zodiac and Saturn, The Chief-Prince Sandalfon over Earth, and The Chief-Prince Metatron over the Sun.)

Lastly it was also upon the Fourth Day of Creation, that Ha'Shem created the Sun, Moon, Stars and Planets. Of which he set his most Holy Angels over.