# Shisha - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. In about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: six are the sides of a cube(it)

Comment: 8 vertices, 12 edges, then how many "sides"? does each face have two, making 12 total?

Comment: Previous: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/474/chamisha-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/507/shiva-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Six are the vowels in the [Babylonian system of nikkud](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99).

Comment: How can there be a correct answer to this question?

Comment: @AdamMosheh: I don't know Isaac's exact criteria, but he always picks an accepted answer for each question in this series.

Comment: @AdamMosheh AFAICT It's strongly related to number of upvotes.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Alex and DoubleAA, I don't have exact criteria. I just pick the one I like best. Upvotes can sway me. Note that even in general "Accepted" doesn't mean "the correct answer." It means "most useful to the asker."

Comment: I count 7: patah/segol, qamatz,  tzere, hiriq, holam, qubutz,
shuruq, shva mobile.

Answer (score 18):

Six are the locations of the Sanctuary: the desert, Gilgal, Shiloh, Nov, Giveon, and Jerusalem.

Comment: From sefer shoftim?

Answer (score 16):

Six are the cities of refuge (for accidental killers).

Comment: Fits the beat!!

Comment: @DoubleAA I tried, yeah, but then had to add the parenthetical comment to make the minimum character count. :-)

Answer (score 14):

Six are the books of the [Mishna Berura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah_Berurah).

Comment: And also the Baal Hatanya's Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: But that doesn't fit the song as nicely. :)

Answer (score 14):

6 Constant Mitzvos

1. To believe in God, and that he created all things.
2. Not to believe in anything else other than God.
3. To believe in God's Oneness.
4. To fear God.
5. To love God.
6. Not to pursue the passions of your heart and stray after your eyes.

Answer (score 12):

Six are the sons of Leah, our fore-mother.

Answer (score 11):

Six are the tribes that stood on Har Gerezim. Six are the tribes that stood on Har Ebal.

Comment: similar: six are the tribes on the left shoulder, six are the tribes on the right shoulder (of the Cohen Gadol of course)

Answer (score 11):

The Jewish women in Egypt gave birth to 6 children at one time

Answer (score 11):

Six are:

- The orders of the Mishnah
- Items on the Seder Plate
- The days of the Six Day War
- The things we remember every day:

  1. Exodus from Egypt ([Devarim 16:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9980#v=3))
  2. Receiving the Torah at Mt. Sinai ([Devarim 4:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9968#v=9))
  3. Amalek ([Devarim 25:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9989#v=17))
  4. The sin of the Golden Calf ([Devarim 9:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9973#v=7))
  5. The Sabbath ([Shemot 20:8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9881#v=8))
  6. Miriam ([Devarim 24:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9988#v=9))

Comment: Ahhh the war lasted _six_ days, that's right!

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, I always forget that one! Btw, what day did the Yom Kippur War start?

Comment: 6 October 1973 IIRC which is also Egypt's [Armed Forces Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armed_Forces_Day#Egypt).

Comment: @DoubleAA. Touche, Wikipedia, touche.

Comment: +1. "Items on the Seder Plate" according to some customs.

Answer (score 11):

Six are the millions of Jews who were murdered by Nazi Germany during WWII, *HY"D*.

Answer (score 11):

6 Aliyos (portions read in the torah) on Yom Kipur

Comment: +1, this is why Yom Kippur is different from all other holidays.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I thought it was that we don't eat anything on yom kippur

Answer (score 10):

Six are the ways Israel was rewarded for Avraham's service to the angels:

1. Because Avraham called for the angels to be brought water, G-d repaid by providing water in the Midbar, in the Yishuv (settlement) and in the Messianic Age (e.g. "Spring water will flow out of Jerusalem (Zech. 14:8));
2. Because Avraham offered the angels a chance to wash their feet, Israel was repaid in the Midbar, Yishuv and the Messianic Age, with "water" to cleanse our sins;
3. Because Avraham invited the angels to recline beneath a tree, G-d spread out a cloud for shelter in the Midbar, succahs in Israel, and a tabernacle in the Messianic Age;
4. Because Avraham fetched a morsel of bread, Israel was repaid with manah in the Midbar, crops in the Yishuv, and the promise of abundant grain in the Messianic Era;
5. Because Avraham ran to the cattle, Israel was repaid with meat in the Midbar, abundant livestck in the Yishuv, and each man will have a heifer and two sheep in the Messianic Era;
6. And because Avraham stood over the angels, G-d attended our needs in the Midbar,leading us with the pillar of fire, listened to our prayers in the Yishuv, and will give us the Messiah.

Source Midrash Rabbah, Genesis, 48:10.

Answer (score 9):

A couple that are related to this week's parsha:

- Six are the types of asham offering (listed in [Zevachim 5:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%94_%D7%94), which we recite in the daily prayers).
- Six are the things that the Kohen has to have in mind while performing the sacrificial service ([ibid. 4:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%93_%D7%95)).

Answer (score 9):

Six are the number of times that the halachah is like Abayei when he argues with Rava - יע"ל קג"ם (Bava Kama 73a).

Answer (score 8):

- 6 are the number of days each week you can work.
- 6 are the number of years you can work the land before Shemita.
- 6 are the number of years you can keep a Jewish slave.

Comment: re: number of days- depends on the week.

Answer (score 8):

Shavuos is on 6 Sivan

Comment: Only sometimes. (Granted it's probably a rov so far.)

Answer (score 8):

6 are the number of steps taken by the bearers of the Ark between each sacrificing of an ox and fatling in the bringing of the Ark to the city of David.

Shmuel II 6:13

> וַיְהִי, כִּי צָעֲדוּ נֹשְׂאֵי אֲרוֹן-יְהוָה--שִׁשָּׁה צְעָדִים:  וַיִּזְבַּח שׁוֹר, וּמְרִיא.

Six are the words in the verse גדלו לה' אתי which we say when we take out the Sefer Torah, which correspond to the six steps taken by the bearers of the Ark between each sacrificing of an ox and fatling in the bringing of the Ark to the city of David (Tosefos Megillah 32a s.v. גוללו)

Answer (score 7):

6th is the day on which Man (and animal) was made.

Answer (score 6):

Holidays we say Hallel

- Sukkos
- Simchas Torah
- Chanuka
- Pesach
- Shavuos
- Rosh Chodesh

Comment: Is Rosh Chodesh technically considered a holiday?

Comment: I guess I can rephrase. Events that we say Hallel.

Comment: Some of those holidays qualify for Chatzi Hallel, and some for Complete Hallel.  You might want to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Also, some of us say Hallel on Israeli Independence Day, as well as on Jerusalem Day...

Answer (score 5):

Points on a jewish star.

Comment: or on a Sherrif's badge...

Comment: Howdy sheriff... Around these parts, your badges are known as davidic shields!

Answer (score 5):

6 are the days of chol hamo'ed Sukkos in Israel.

6 are the number of tefachim in a cubit.

Comment: What kind of cubit?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think it's referred to in the talmud without any special name and I will follow suit.  Although you can call it benoni if you wish.

Answer (score 5):

The Midrash in Bamidbar Rabbah 12:17 says that there are **six** specific mitzvos that a Jewish king is commanded about every day:

- Not to have too many wives/concubines           (Devarim 17:17)
- Not to have too many horses                                (Devarim 17:16)
- Not to have too much silver and gold                 (Devarim 17:17)
- Not to pervert justice (when judging a case)     (Devarim 16:19)
- Not to show favoritism (when judging a case)  (Devarim 16:19)
- Not to take a bribe (when judging a case)          (Devarim 16:19)

Answer (score 3):

Those who went from *Bavel* to *Y'huda* with *Z'rubavel* ([*Ezra* 2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35a02.htm#64)) traveled with pack animals in the ratio of six (more precisely, 6.13) people per animal (verses 64–67: 49,897 people to 8136 animals).

Comment: How and why did this enter your mind when you were learning the psukim?! You gotta find a good drasha to tack this on to.

Comment: @user6591, when learning the _p'sukim_ I noticed that there were very few animals per person and wondered just how few, so computed it. That brought me to this page. `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

Sidrei mishnah.

Branches coming out the side of the menorah in the mikdash.

Hours the Rambam says to wait between meat and milk.

Wings on an angel.

Years till average child is bar daas.

Steps one takes after shmoneh esrei till one can walk away, three backwards and three forwards.

Total count of all the lechem mishna from shabbos.

All the matzahs from both seder nights.

Comment: "Total count of all the lechem mishna from shabbos." Only if you are eating the minimum number of meals and eating both loaves at each.

Comment: "Sidrei mishna": [was done already](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16409).

Answer (score 3):

[Six are the things](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%93) that preceded the creation of the world:

1. The Torah
2. The Throne of Glory
3. The Patriarchs
4. Israel
5. The Beis Hamikdash
6. The name of Mashiach

Answer (score 2):

R. Menachem and R. Yehoshua b. Levi said in the name of R. Levi: A builder requires six things: water, earth, timber, stones, canes, and iron. And even if yon say, He is wealthy and does not need canes, yet he surely requires a measuring rod, as it is written, And a measuring reed in his hand (Ezekiel 40:3).

Answer (score 2):

**Six** - A man is obligated to provide food/ sustenance to his sons and daughters until they are 6 years of age ([Ketubot 65b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.65b?lang=bi), codified by the **Shulchan Aruch**, [Even Haezer 71:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.71.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

While a person may "technically" be exempt from providing food or sustenance to their children past the age of 6, **Beis Din would never allow this to happen and they would force the father to provide the child with food and sustenance until at least the child's Bar/Bat Mitzvah**. (SA, EH ibid).

Answer (score 1):

6 feet in 4 amot.

Comment: According to whom?

Comment: And the foot size of which man?

Answer (score 1):

Six is the number of days one is required to remove oneself from one's house prior to entering the camp of the Shekhinah (RaSh"I on [Shemot 24:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9885#v=16&showrashi=true); Yoma 3B [[English](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Yoma.pdf)], [[Original](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=3b&format=text)]).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Shoham stones worn on the Cohen Gadol's shoulders,

Exodus 28:10:

> שִׁשָּׁה֙ מִשְּׁמֹתָ֔ם עַ֖ל הָאֶ֣בֶן הָאֶחָ֑ת וְאֶת־שְׁמ֞וֹת
>   הַשִּׁשָּׁ֧ה הַנּוֹתָרִ֛ים עַל־הָאֶ֥בֶן הַשֵּׁנִ֖ית כְּתוֹלְדֹתָֽם׃
>
> six of their names on the one stone, and the names of the six that
>   remain on the other stone, according to their birth.

For the "original" menorah:

Exodus 25:32:

> וְשִׁשָּׁ֣ה קָנִ֔ים יֹצְאִ֖ים מִצִּדֶּ֑יהָ שְׁלֹשָׁ֣ה ׀ קְנֵ֣י
>   מְנֹרָ֗ה מִצִּדָּהּ֙ הָאֶחָ֔ד וּשְׁלֹשָׁה֙ קְנֵ֣י מְנֹרָ֔ה מִצִּדָּ֖הּ
>   הַשֵּׁנִֽי׃
>
> And there shall be six branches going out of the sides thereof: three
>   branches of the candlestick out of the one side thereof, and three
>   branches of the candle-stick out of the other side thereof;

Comment: The branches were done already: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40395

Answer (score 1):

The Torah is preceded [by six things](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%97):

1. **Kedem**,
2. **me'az**,
3. **me'olam**,
4. **me'rosh**, and
5. **mi'lekadmin** (which count as two).

Answer (score 1):

Per [Greg Killian:](https://betemunah.org/six.html)

There is a proliferation of the number six (and its multiples) in the Megillah of Ruth:

Shuv (return) occurs twelve times in chapter one.

6 times: “Shuv” indicates a return to Beit-Lechem (vv. 6,7,10,21,22,22).

6 times: “Shuv” indicates a return to Moav (vv. 8, 11,12,15,15,16).

M'lak'tot (gleaners) occurs twelve times in chapter two.

In Ruth 3:14 and 3:16 we see six measures of barley.

Midrash Rabbah - Ruth V:6 AND BOAZ SAID UNTO HER AT MEAL TIME: COME HITHER, AND EAT OF THE BREAD, AND DIP THY MORSEL IN THE VINEGAR. AND SHE SAT BESIDE THE REAPERS; AND THEY REACHED HER PARCHED CORN, AND SHE DID EAT AND WAS SATISFIED AND LEFT THEREOF (II, 14). R. Jonathan interpreted this verse in six ways.

Midrash Rabbah - Ruth VII:2 Simon said: The meaning is that as a reward for, AND HE MEASURED SIX BARLEYS AND LAID [THEM] ON HER,1 he was vouchsafed that there should arise from her six righteous men, each one of them possessing six outstanding virtues, viz. David, Hezekiah, Josiah, Hananiah, Mishael and Azariah, Daniel, and the Messiah. David, as it is said, Skilful in playing, and a mighty man of valor, and a man of war, and prudent in affairs, and a comely person, and the Lord is with him (I Sam. XVI, 18); Hezekiah, as it is said, That the government may be increased, and of peace there be no end, upon the throne of David, and upon his kingdom, to establish it, and to uphold it, through justice and through righteousness (Isa. IX, 6). And his name is called Pele- joez-el-gibbor-abi-ad-sar-shalom (ib. 5). Some observe that l'marbeh (be increased) is written with a closed mem. Josiah, as it is said, For he shall be as a tree planted by the waters, and that spreadeth out its roots by the river, etc. (Jer. XVII, 8). Hananiah, Mishael, and Azariah, as it is said, Youths in whom there was no blemish, but fair to look on, and skilful in all wisdom, and skilful in knowledge, and discerning in thought, and such as had ability  (Dan. I, 4). Daniel, as it is said, A surpassing spirit, and knowledge, and understanding, interpreting of dreams, and declaring of riddles, and loosing of knots, were found in the same Daniel (ib. v, 12). The Messiah, as it is said, And the spirit of the Lord shall rest upon him, the spirit of wisdom and understanding, etc. (Isa. XI, 2).

The name Boaz appears three times six times in sefer Ruth.

The name Ruth appears two times six times in sefer Ruth. (Both of these counts ignore the genealogy at the end of the Megillah which is not, properly, part of the story).

Answer (score 0):

Six are the number of millennium from creation we must wait before the messianic age.

Comment: The last two thousand years of the six millennium are called "the days of Moshiach"

Comment: *Must*?? [15 char]

Comment: Must may have been too strong of a word, but yeah, according to some. I'll try to find the source for it. It has something to do with 2K year cycles (2K pre- prophecy, 2K prophecy, 2K present) and the 6th millennium from creation being the equivalent to Friday, which is the 6th day of the week which leads into Shabbat, the ultimate day of rest. Must be some chasidisha thing.