# Tish'a - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. In about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/539/shemona-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/570/asara-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nine are the total number of Cities of Refuge to be designated in the Land of Israel, when its boundaries are broadened ([Deut. 19:9](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%98)).

Incidentally, Maimonides ([Laws of Kings 11:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=83&perek=11&halocha=2)) uses this verse as one of the proofs that the Torah speaks of a future era of Moshiach (may he come soon!), since the broadened boundaries of which this verse speaks have never yet come to pass, "and G-d did not give a command in vain."

Comment: Checkmark for fusing the number, halacha, derash, and an appropriate thought for the impending Shabbat and holiday, with sources!

Answer (score 7):

Nine were the cubits of [Og's bed](http://thinkingtorah.blogspot.com/2007/07/og-melech-habashans-bed.html) ([Deut. 3](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0503.htm):11).

Answer (score 6):

Nine are the grades of olive oil ([Mishnah, Menachos 8:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%97_%D7%93)).

Nine are the regions of the Land of Israel, for purposes of the Shemittah laws ([Mishnah, Shevi'is 9:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%98_%D7%91)).

Answer (score 4):

Nine are the [minutes a person should wait between eating](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-issues-measurements.htm#footnotesC), if s/he can't fast on Yom Kippur.  (Please consult a rabbi first!)

Nine are the [months before a calf is born](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_gestation_period_of_a_cow).  (See Sforno's introductory essay to Chumash.)

Answer (score 4):

Nine is this year!
([לפ"ק](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5770_%28Hebrew_year%29))

Comment: I want to get it, but I don't get it.

Comment: "Tesha" = taf-shin-yain = 770.

Answer (score 3):

There are 9 places in Tanach where the letter "ב" comes 3 in a row in the same word.

1 - Melachim2 25:28 - בבבל

2 - Yeshayahu 48:14 - בבבל

3 - Yirmiyahu 29:22 - בבבל

4 - Yirmiyahu 51:44 - בבבל

5 - Yirmiyahu 52:32 - בבבל

6 - Zecharya 2:12 - בבבת

7 - Ezra 5:17 - בבבל

8 - Ezra 6:1 - בבבל

9 - Divrei HaYomim2 36:7 - בבבל

Comment: See also [Nechemiah 9 23](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%98_%D7%9B%D7%92)

Answer (score 3):

9 is the number of **letters in the shortest pasuk** in Divrei Hayamim, in all of Kesuvim, and in all of Tanach.

(**אָדָם שֵׁת אֱנוֹשׁ**" - (דברי הימים א' - א', א'

Answer (score 3):

**9** - is the number of Parah Adumahs that have existed-- and utilized for ritual purposes-- thus far in Jewish history.

The mishna in [Maseches Parah 3:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Parah.3.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) lists these 9 Parah Adumahs:

- 1)  משֶׁה
- 2)   מֵעֶזְרָא
- 3) שִׁמְעוֹן הַצַּדִּיק **(did 2)**
- 5)  וְיוֹחָנָן כֹּהֵן גָּדוֹל **(did 2)**
- 7) אֶלְיְהוֹעֵינַי בֶּן הַקּוֹף
- 8) וַחֲנַמְאֵל הַמִּצְרִי
- 9) וְיִשְׁמָעֵאל בֶּן פִּיאָבִי

The **Rambam** in [Hilchos Parah Adumah 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Red_Heifer.3.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) codifies this number...

> וְ**תֵשַׁע פָּרוֹת אֲדֻמּוֹת** נַעֲשׂוּ מִשֶּׁנִּצְטַוּוּ בְּמִצְוָה זוֹ עַד שֶׁחָרַב הַבַּיִת בַּשְּׁנִיָּה. רִאשׁוֹנָה עָשָׂה משֶׁה רַבֵּנוּ. שְׁנִיָּה עָשָׂה עֶזְרָא. וְשֶׁבַע מֵעֶזְרָא עַד חֻרְבַּן הַבַּיִת
>
> **Nine red heifers** [existed] from the time that we were commanded to fulfill this mitzvah until the destruction of the second Beis Hamikdash. The first parah adumah was done Moshe Rabeinu. The second was done by Ezra. Seven more parah adumahs [existed] from Ezra until the destruction of the second Beis Hamikdash.

---

... before concluding that IH one day, *b'mheirah b'yameinu*:

> וְהָעֲשִׂירִית יַעֲשֶׂה הַמֶּלֶךְ הַמָּשִׁיחַ מְהֵרָה יִגָּלֶה אָמֵן כֵּן יְהִי רָצוֹן:
>
> And the tenth will be prepared by the Melech HaMashiach; may he speedily redeem us. Amen, may it be G‑d's will.

Answer (score 2):

Nine are the sefiros for which Malchus is the receptor, and the transmitter of their effects to the lower worlds.

Shaarei Orah, Shaar Alef

Answer (score 2):

... is what you get if you add up every three letters of the Alef Beis (for that matter any three numbers according to the numbering of the Alef Beis) if you start from 
Beis:

2+3+4=9,
5+6+7= 18 and 1+8=9,

8+9+10=27 and 2+7=9, etc.

If you don't believe me figure the rest for yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Nine are the Brachos in Shemona Esrei on Rosh HaShana at Musaf

Answer (score 2):

Nine are the portions (out of ten) of chatter that went to women, and beauty that went to Jerusalem.

Comment: 10 measures of intelligence (hokhma) were given to the world; the Land of Israel received nine while the rest of the world received one.
10 measures of beauty (yofi) were given to the world; Jerusalem received 9 while the rest of the world received 1.
10 measures of wealth (osher) were given to the world; Rome received 9 while the rest of the world received 1.
10 measures of poverty (aniyut) were given to the world; Babylon received nine while the rest of the world received one.
10 measures of magic (keshafim) were given to the world; Egypt received nine while the rest of the world received 1.

Answer (score 1):

Nine entered Gan Eden during their lifetimes:... Ebed-melech the Cushite and Bithiah daughter of Pharoah (Derech Eretz Zuta 1;Encyclopedia of biblical personalities p. 123)

Answer (score 1):

R’ Yona (Shaarei Teshuva 3:178-186.) lists nine different categories of lies. In order of severity, they are:

- a. People who cheat in business, causing others financial loss;
- b. People who exploit others after gaining their trust through deception;
- c. People whose lies cause others to lose out on some gain or benefit that was coming to them;
- d. People who fabricate stories merely for the sake of lying;
- e. People who hold out the promise of giving another person material goods while never intending to follow up on their promise;
- f. People who intend to keep a promise but do not honor their commitment;
- g. People who act as though they did a favor or a good deed for another;
- h. People who praise themselves for virtues that they do not possess;
- i. People who change minor details when retelling an episode.

Answer (score 1):

Nine kavin is the measure of several things in the Talmud. For example, in [Berachot 22a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=22&format=pdf):

> תנו רבנן בעל קרי שנתנו עליו תשעה קבין מים טהור
>
> Our Rabbis taught: A ba'al keri on whom nine kabs of water have been thrown is clean.
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_22.html))

Answer (score 0):

The Gemara in [Bava Kamma 55a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.55a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> א"ר יהושע הרואה טי"ת בחלומו סימן יפה לו
>
> *Rabbi Yehoshua says: If one sees the letter tet in his dream, it is a good sign for him.*

Answer (score 0):

One of the more obvious one - but seeing as it is relevant now...

9 are the days concluding the three weeks and climaxing with Tisha B'Av

Answer (score 0):

[Mishna Taanis 4:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Taanit.4.5?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi) writes:

> **זְמַן עֲצֵי כֹהֲנִים וְהָעָם, תִּשְׁעָה**. בְּאֶחָד בְּנִיסָן, בְּנֵי אָרַח בֶּן יְהוּדָה. בְּעֶשְׂרִים בְּתַמּוּז, בְּנֵי דָוִד בֶּן יְהוּדָה. בַּחֲמִשָּׁה בְאָב, בְּנֵי פַרְעֹשׁ בֶּן יְהוּדָה. בְּשִׁבְעָה בוֹ, בְּנֵי יוֹנָדָב בֶּן רֵכָב. בַּעֲשָׂרָה בוֹ, בְּנֵי סְנָאָה בֶן בִּנְיָמִין. בַּחֲמִשָּׁה עָשָׂר בּוֹ, בְּנֵי זַתּוּא בֶן יְהוּדָה, וְעִמָּהֶם כֹּהֲנִים וּלְוִיִּם וְכָל מִי שֶׁטָּעָה בְשִׁבְטוֹ, וּבְנֵי גוֹנְבֵי עֱלִי בְּנֵי קוֹצְעֵי קְצִיעוֹת. בְּעֶשְׂרִים בּוֹ, בְּנֵי פַחַת מוֹאָב בֶּן יְהוּדָה. בְּעֶשְׂרִים בֶּאֱלוּל, בְּנֵי עָדִין בֶּן יְהוּדָה. בְּאֶחָד בְּטֵבֵת שָׁבוּ בְנֵי פַרְעֹשׁ שְׁנִיָּה. בְּאֶחָד בְּטֵבֵת לֹא הָיָה בוֹ מַעֲמָד, שֶׁהָיָה בוֹ הַלֵּל וְקָרְבַּן מוּסָף וְקָרְבַּן עֵצִים:
>
> ***The times [of the delivery] of wood [for the altar] by priests and people, were on nine appointed days**; on the first of Nissan, the family Arah of Yehudah [delivered]; on the twentieth of Tamuz, the family of David of Yehudah; on the fifth of Av, the family of Parosh of Jehudah; on the seventh, the family of Jonadav ben Rechav; on the tenth, the family of Sinha of Benjamin; on the fifteenth, the family of Zatu of Jehudah, and with them priests and Levites, and all those who did not know from what tribe [they were descended], also the family of Gonve Eli, and the family of Kotzei Ketziot; and on the twentieth the family Pachat Moav of Jehudah; on the twentieth of Elul, the family Adin of Jehudah; on the first of Tevet, the family Parosh, [offered a] second time. There was no meeting of the standing men on the first of Tevet; because Hallel was recited, and an additional sacrifice and wood-offering were brought [on that day].*

(Sefaria translation & notation)

Answer (score 0):

Again another obvious one - inspired by the song...

Gemara Nidda 38a:

> אמר רב אדא בר אהבה ש"מ קסבר רבי יהודה שיפורא גרים איני והא אמר שמואל אין אשה מתעברת ויולדת אלא למאתים ושבעים ואחד יום או למאתים ושבעים ושנים יום או למאתים ושבעים ושלשה
>
> *Rav Adda bar Ahava says: Conclude from the baraita that Rabbi Yehuda holds that the blast of the shofar at the beginning of the ninth month causes the blood emitted during that month to be pure. That is to say, once the ninth months begins, any blood emitted does not render her a zava. The Gemara asks: Is that so, that the entire ninth month of pregnancy is suitable for giving birth, and therefore any blood seen during the ninth month is attributed to the imminent labor? But doesn’t Shmuel say that a woman becomes pregnant and gives birth only after 271 days, which is a full nine months, or after 272 days, or after 273 days? She will not, however, give birth during the ninth month itself.*

(Sefaria translation & notation)

and Rashi elucidates:

> ...או למאתים ושבעים ואחד - **דהוו להו ט' חדשים שלמים**
>
> *"Or 271 days" - **That is 9 complete months***

Answer (score 0):

Channah said Hashem's name nine times in her prayer.

([Berachos 29a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.29a.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))