# Asara - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows ten?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point on [Chol Hamo'ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chol_HaMoed), I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: מכווין מלאכתו למועד?

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/549/tisha-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/645/achad-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ten types of tum'ah (impurity) that can originate from a person ([Mishnah, Kelim 1:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%94)).

And more positively, ten levels of spatial kedushah (sanctity), beginning with the Land of Israel and ending with the Holy of Holies in the Beis Hamikdash ([ibid., 1:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%95) and following mishnayos).

Comment: Leshana haba-ah biyerushalayim habenuya!

Answer (score 10):

The minhag is to place 10 pieces of bread while doing Bedikas Chametz... See [Bedikas Chometz - 10 pieces of bread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6589/bedikas-chometz-10-pieces-of-bread)

Answer (score 9):

Ten are the sons of Rav Pappa mentioned in a siyum.

Answer (score 9):

10 generations from Adam to Noah

10 generations from Noah to Avraham

[7 generations from Avraham to Moshe]

10 generations (links) from Moshe to Yehuda ben Tabai and Shimon ben Shatach

Answer (score 8):

Ten challenges of Avraham.

Comment: Better translation than "tests."

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Why?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, because "test" generally implies that the one applying it is trying to learn something. As the One applying these was the Omniscient, that could not have been the purpose.

Answer (score 8):

Ten Makkos Makkos ten, the Mitzrim were punished again and again

Comment: I like your rhyme.

Comment: @AdamMosheh It's from a famous children's song.

Comment: I immediately heard my little sister singing this song. :)

Answer (score 7):

The world was created with ten statements.

Answer (score 7):

Ten Sefirot (total!)

Comment: True no matter what way you count them! (Sefer Yetzirah)

Comment: @Yahu - What do you mean by that?  And where does teh Sefer haYetzirah say that?

Comment: @AdamMosheh I imagine he means that sometimes kabbalists include Keser instead of Daas, and vice versa. Either way, it's still ten. The quote from Sefer Yetzirah is (I imagine) `Ten sefirot of nothingness; ten and not nine, ten and not eleven.` Where in Sefer Yetzirah it is probably depends on which edition you have.

Answer (score 7):

Ten are the [pedigrees of Israel](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mishnah/Seder_Nashim/Tractate_Kiddushin/Chapter_4/1)

Comment: Ten pedigrees emigrated from Babylonia [to Israel]:
Priestly, Levitical, [Ordinary] Jewish,
Invalidated Priestly, Converted, Freed,
Mamzeric, Nathinitic, Silent Ones and Foundlings.

Answer (score 7):

10 is the amount of people you need for a Minyan

Answer (score 7):

Aseres Yemei Teshuva

Answer (score 6):

Ten are the sons of Binyamin. [Bereishis 46:21](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0146.htm)

Answer (score 6):

You are supposed to give 10% of your earnings to Tzedaka - known as Maaser

Comment: Is this a chiyuv or a minhag? What's the source?

Comment: @Yehoshua - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59471/source-for-maaser-money

Answer (score 5):

Ten are the [Ten Declarations](http://www.jewfaq.org/10.htm)!

You want to count The Commandments? Wait about 603 business days.

And get off my lawn.

Comment: That's one decadeclaration, in case anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 5):

Haman haRasha had ten sons (cf. 9th chapter of Megillat Esther).

Comment: ...or ten listed sons, anyway. (See _Bavli M'gila_.) +1.

Answer (score 4):

Ten of the twelve spies (meraglim) who were sent by Moses to scout out the Land of Israel came back with a negative report.

Answer (score 3):

There are 10 places in Tanach where the letter "א" Aleph is immediately followed by another "א" Aleph in the same word.

1 - Breishis 12:3 אאר

2 - Yeshayahu 45:5 - אאזרך

3 - Yeshayahu 48:9 - אאריך

4 - Micha 2:12 - אאסף

5 - Iyov 6:11 - אאריך

6 - Iyov 9:16 - אאמין

7 - Iyov 16:5 - אאמצכם

8 - Iyov 33:33 - ואאלפך

9 - Daniel 4:12 - בדתאא

10 - Daniel 4:20 - בדתאא

Comment: Is there any significance to this? There's also 12 times where you find טט in one word, 8 times where there is עע in one word, and 937 where you find יי in one word.

Comment: @DoubleAA Need there be significance? I don't remember that being a requirement in the OP.

Comment: @ezra It is explicit in the newer MY Series posts. But even if it's not literally required, it's clearly stupid to make a list of insignificant 10s...

Answer (score 3):

10 are the words in the blessing Hamotzi.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29291/759

Comment: Similarly, Ten are the words in שלא עשני אישה

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt only if you count in base 9.

Comment: @Yez, the mnemonic I was thinking of included אמן

Answer (score 2):

Ten is the number of the Lost Tribes of Israel, who were exiled to Assyria because of their misdeeds. (II Kings 17:6)

The Talmud (Sanhedrin 110b) brings several opinions concerning the eventual fate of these tribes. According to Rabbi Akiva, they will never return. According to Rabbi Eliezer, they will indeed return to the Land of Israel eventually. In the view of Rabbi Shimon ben Yehudah, the fate of the tribes depends on whether or not they repent.

The entire daf is quite interesting; I'd suggest looking at it for further reading.

Answer (score 2):

**10** - upon marriage, 10 is the number of things a man is obligated to provide for his wife (**Shulchan Aruch**, [Even Haezer 69:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.69.1-2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

- 1) food (***d'oraisa***)
- 2) clothing (***d'oraisa***)
- 3) marital relations (***d'oraisa***)
- 4) *ikkar* (the core) of her ketubah
- 5) doctor bills/ healing her
- 6) redeeming her if she is taken captive
- 7) her burial
- 8) if she becomes a widow, that she be sustained from his possessions/ live in his house after his death
- 9) her children be sustained after her husband's death until they are engaged
- 10) her sons from him inherit her ketubah more than their portion of inheritance that is with their siblings

Answer (score 1):

Number of words used to count a minyon in [Tehillim 28:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16249#v=9)

הוֹשִׁיעָה אֶת עַמֶּךָ וּבָרֵךְ אֶת נַחֲלָתֶךָ וּרְעֵם וְנַשְּׂאֵם עַד הָעוֹלָם

Comment: Add explicitly that it is used to count a minyon (number of words in [tehillim 28:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16249#v=9))

Comment: @sabbahillel Any source for this?

Comment: @Kazibácsi just from having been in shul when it is used to count.

Comment: @sabbahillel An elderly person taught it to me long ago, but it'd be nice to find a source.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 15:3 (https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.15.3?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).

Answer (score 1):

Ten are the kosher mammals:

> שׁ֕וֹר שֵׂ֥ה כְשָׂבִ֖ים וְשֵׂ֥ה עִזִּֽים׃ אַיָּ֥ל וּצְבִ֖י וְיַחְמ֑וּר
>   וְאַקּ֥וֹ וְדִישֹׁ֖ן וּתְא֥וֹ וָזָֽמֶר׃

Answer (score 1):

**10** - are the principles that the Torah requires to effect a *halachik* divorce  (**Rambam**, [Hilchos Geirushin 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

- **1)** That a man must voluntarily initiate the divorce. ([ibid 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **2)** The method of divorce must be done in writing and nothing else. ([ibid 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **3)** That subject of the *get* must make clear that the husband is divorcing his wife and releasing her from his domain. ([ibid 1:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **4)** The essence of the text of the *get* should express the severing of the connection between the husband and wife. ([ibid 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **5)** That *get* must be written *l'shma*- ie specifically for her. ([ibid 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **6)** After the *get* is written, it must not require any other action except delivery to the woman (For example: writing a *get* on the horn of a cow and then detaching said horn and giving it as a *get* would be invalid). ([ibid 1:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **7)** The husband must give/ transfer over the *get* to her. ([ibid 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **8)** The husband must give her the *get* in the presence of witnesses. ([ibid 1:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **9)** The husband must give her the *get* for the sake of divorce. ([ibid 1:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **10)** The husband or his agent must be the one who gives her the *get*. ([ibid 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

(the rest of the requirements of a *get*- ie the date, the signature of the witnesses, etc- are all *mi'drabanan*)

Answer (score 0):

- [Ten keilim and Ten oros](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380568/jewish/Shattered-Vessels.htm) (cf. [Alex's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16717/1059) on the J.SE question entitled [What is Shevirat Hakeilim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16715/1059))

Comment: Kinda sorta a duplicate of Chanoch's answer of Ten Sefirot.

Answer (score 0):

Ten mitzvos given to Benei Noach that are not included in the Sheva Mitzvos that they might be chayiv in.

Comment: See further [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77476/9682).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81634/9682

Answer (score 0):

In the current Nusach Ashkenaz, the word מנוחה of some form is mentioned ten times in Shabbos Mincha. As for significance, well, [that’s already been asked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83000/9682).

Answer (score 0):

Laban would renege ten times on any agreement he made with Yaakov. - Breshis Rabbah 73:9

Answer (score 0):

Dovid HaMelech wrote the book of Tehillim (Psalms) through ten elders of the previous generation.

([Bava Basra 14b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.14b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Answer (score 0):

Ten is the age for the study of Mishna

([Pirkei Avos 5:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))