# Achad asar - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows eleven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point after Pesach, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/570/asara-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/696/shneim-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eleven are the levels of divine inspiration (or prophecy) achievable by any Jew (under the prophecy level of Moshe which is not attainable by any other than Moshe) according to Rambam in Moreh Nevuchim.

Comment: Moreh Nevuchim 2:45

Answer (score 12):

Eleven is the maximum number of consecutive days when the Torah can be read (outside of Eretz Yisrael):

If the first day of Sukkos falls on a Tuesday, then we have a reading on Monday (part of the regular weekly Torah portion), then the nine days of Sukkos/Shemini Atzeres/Simchas Torah, and then Thursday (back to the regular weekly portion).

Comment: Runners up with 10 days beginning on: 14 nissan saturday, 15 tishrei thursday, 15 tishrei saturday, and the longest possible in Israel 24 kislev thursday or 24 kislev saturday

Answer (score 7):

Yosef dreamt that his 11 brothers will come and bow down to him

Comment: Alright Gershon! You got my vote!

Comment: Hey - you made me work for it

Answer (score 6):

Eleven are the weekly Torah portions (out of 54) that don't begin with the letter vav.

Correspondingly, eleven are the chapters of the first part of [Tanya](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/6237/jewish/Lessons-in-Tanya.htm) (also out of 54) that don't begin with the letter vav.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/137078/jewish/Vav.htm I hear it was ten.

Answer (score 5):

...are the ingredients of the Kitores, the incense offering.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 Hebrew words in Tanach that consist of 11 letters.

יחזקאל 20:44 - וכעלילותיכם,

יחזקאל 16:47 - וכתועבותיהן,

אסתר 9:3 - והאחשדרפנים

Answer (score 3):

11 are the sidros in sefer shemos and devarim

Comment: Not everyone agrees that Nitzavim and Vayelech are different Sidros.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not everyone agrees that they aren't.  I noticed you weren't bothered with Alex's reference to 54 parshiyos (above in this thread) though.  What is 12 + 11 + 10 + 10 + 10?

Comment: 54 isn't part of his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin was born (and Rachel died) on the 11th of Marcheshvan - Yalkut Shimoni, Shemos 162

Comment: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/11/is-today-yahrzeit-of-rachel-imenu.html