# Lowest counting number not in mishna

Tags: mishna, song-poetry

Some years back, i heard a song that counted using Mishna quotes.  It was to the tune of (this website's anthem), Echad mi yodea.

The first few lines, as best I remember them:

> אֶחָד הַחוֹפֵר בּוֹר (Bava Kamma 5:5) 
>   שְׁנַיִם אוֹחֲזִין בְּטַלִּית,
>   (Bava Metzia 1:1) 
>   שְׁלשָׁה שֶׁאָכְלוּ כְאֶחָד (Berakhot 7:1)
>   אַרְבָּעָה אֲבוֹת נְזִיקִין (Bava Kamma 1:1)

It goes as high as 11, and can be found [here](https://youtu.be/KltSST7OX4Y).

Can one count higher?  Certainly there are the 15 women from Yevamot 1:1, but I don't know if the intervening numbers appear.  It seems odd that 12 would be absent, but also odd that 12, if present, wasn't included.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tag:mi-yodeya-series]. In particular: [12](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/696/shneim-asar-mi-yodeya), [13](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/716/shelosha-asar-mi-yodeya), and [14](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/762/arbaa-asar-mi-yodeya).

Comment: 12 and 13 appear, among other Mishnayos, together in Niddah 5:6 as the respective ages for Bar and Bas Mitzvah.

Comment: @Alex, I thought related but different enough.  I'm happy to let someone else make that call.

Comment: All in one Mishnah: מגילה נקראת באחד עשר בשנים עשר בשלשה עשר בארבעה עשר בחמשה עשר

Comment: I think the actual original song goes all the way to twenty-three.

Comment: @Alex Brilliant!

Comment: @Schmerel, I'd love to see that.  Any idea where I can find it?  23 itself is going to be in Sanhedrin, I presume about a court of 23 judges.  I presume all the counting numbers up to 23 are included, correct?