# Lechem mishneh - Two questions

Tags: halacha, shabbat, challah-shabbat-bread

1) When holding the Lechem Mishneh together while making the bracha - Do both challot have to be touching ? What if one challah was wrapped in cellophane or in a bag (yet held next to the other challah during the bracha) - would that be ok ?

2) Does the second challah need to be edible ? What if it was frozen solid ?

Comment: I think #2 is a duplicate somewhere here. The answer to #2 is it is a Machlokes.

Comment: Closely related to #1: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29286

Comment: Shouldn't these be separated into two posts?

Comment: done. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35626/lechem-mishneh-do-both-challot-have-to-be-touching

Comment: done. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35627/using-a-frozen-challah-for-lechem-mishneh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rabbi *Chayim Pinchas* Scheinberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Pinchas_Scheinberg) is paraphrased (in [*The Radiance of Shabbos*](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/radh.html) by [Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simcha_Bunim_Cohen)) as saying that, even if one will not cut into the second loaf, he should hold it unwrapped. However, Rabbi Cohen gives no [reason for this rule](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29286). [*Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shemirat_Shabbat_Kehilchatah), chapter 55, footnote 38, also says it should be unwrapped, citing *Mishna B'rura* [who is (eventually) quoting [the *Y'rushalmi*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29291)].

*Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah* 55:12 says frozen bread is okay, citing [*B'tzel Hachochma* (volume 3, 110:4)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1809&pgnum=195) and [*Riv'vos Efrayim* (volume 2, 115:2)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1534&pgnum=186). (They allow it because one *can* extend his meal until the bread is edible; *SSK* notes, though, that he heard from [Rabbi *Sh'lomo Zalman* Auerbach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Zalman_Auerbach) that it can't be used unless one *plans* to extend his meal that long, in which case the bread is "כרותח שצריכים להמתין עד שיצטנן" [which I don't understand].)