# Lechem Mishneh - Do both challot have to be touching?

Tags: shabbat, blessing, challah-shabbat-bread

When holding the Lechem Mishneh together while making the bracha - Do both challot have to be touching ? What if one challah was wrapped in cellophane or in a bag (yet held next to the other challah during the bracha) - would that be ok ?

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29286

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rabbi *Chayim Pinchas* Scheinberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Pinchas_Scheinberg) is paraphrased (in [*The Radiance of Shabbos*](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/radh.html) by [Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simcha_Bunim_Cohen)) as saying that, even if one will not cut into the second loaf, he should hold it unwrapped. However, Rabbi Cohen gives no [reason for this rule](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29286). [*Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shemirat_Shabbat_Kehilchatah), chapter 55, footnote 38, also says it should be unwrapped, citing *Mishna B'rura* [who is (eventually) quoting [the *Y'rushalmi*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29291)].

Answer (score 7):

http://revach.net/article.php?id=3830

> Shevet HaKehosi (2:114) says that it should be taken out of the bag
>   and L'Chatchila the two Challos should touch.