# Using a Frozen Challah for Lechem Mishneh

Tags: shabbat, blessing, challah-shabbat-bread

If the only available Challah I have for Lechem Mishneh is frozen solid - may it be used ?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35582/1362  http://alleywaystotorah.blogspot.com/2007/05/frozen-kallah-no-frozen-challah-yes.html

Comment: I think this was intended to be a split of that question. As was proposed in the comments there.

Comment: are both frozen or just one of them?

Comment: @Yishai I need to be able to eat at least one of them for the Bracha

Comment: @eramm, well, yeah, but the question doesn't make clear which scenario you are thinking of.

Comment: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/849029/rabbi-jonathan-ziring/halacha-al-regel-achat-using-frozen-bread-for-lechem-mishna/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah* 55:12 says frozen bread is okay, citing [*B'tzel Hachochma* (volume 3, 110:4)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1809&pgnum=195) and [*Riv'vos Efrayim* (volume 2, 115:2)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1534&pgnum=186). (They allow it because one *can* extend his meal until the bread is edible; *SSK* notes, though, that he heard from [Rabbi *Sh'lomo Zalman* Auerbach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Zalman_Auerbach) that it can't be used unless one *plans* to extend his meal that long, in which case the bread is "כרותח שצריכים להמתין עד שיצטנן" [which I don't understand].)

Answer (score 4):

Rabbi Shmuel Kamenetsky in his Sefer Kovetz Halachos writes that one may use a frozen Challa for Lechem Mishna. Furthermore he writes one may use a Challa that is not Pas Yisrael for the second Challa even if he is Makpid on Pas Yisrael. (Do not have the Sefer in front of me now. I will add in the exact location when I have the Sefer)

[Tzitz Eliezer 14:40](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14513&st=&pgnum=89) also permits using a frozen Challa for Lechem Mishna and a Challa that is not Pas Yisrael.

Comment: Kudos for adding the Pas Yisroel scenario. I was wondering about such a situation.