# Would having a matzah encased in glass work for lechem mishnah?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, meal-seudah

I just came across the idea in a [tweet](https://twitter.com/jacklanger/status/1507907125208625153?s=20&t=I1z7q_uAMsLqSZbjIRGivA) of encasing a matzah in a piece of glass on a challah board to enable you to always have lechem mishnah. It was a funny idea, but that got me wondering whether this would actually be halachically acceptable?

[image]

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29291/759