# How many prophets were there and who were they?

Tags: number, tanach, historical-figures, navi-prophets

How many prophets are recognized by Judaism, and what were their names?

I found a website that claims the number of prophets is 124000. Is this true?

Are all of their speeches or writings documented? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Talmud (Megillah 14a) writes:

> הרבה נביאים עמדו להם לישראל, כפלים כיוצאי מצרים, אלא, נבואה שהוצרכה לדורות - נכתבה, ושלא הוצרכה - לא נכתבה.‏
>   Many prophets arose for the Jews: more than twice the number of Jews in the Exodus [1200000, but this language is likely meant to be understood as a really, really big number]. However, those prophesies which were needed for future generations were recorded while those that were not needed for future generations were not recorded.

So there were a whole lot of prophets in history. The 48 men and 7 women who are recorded as prophets are (as listed in Rashi to that piece of Talmud):

1. Abraham
2. Sarah
3. Isaac
4. Jacob
5. Miriam
6. Aaron
7. Moses
8. Joshua
9. Devora
10. Pinchas
11. Eli
12. Elkana
13. Hannah
14. Samuel
15. David
16. Abigail
17. Gad
18. Nathan
19. Solomon
20. Ido
21. Michayahu
22. Ovadiah
23. Achiyah
24. Yehu
25. Azaryah
26. Chaziel
27. Eliezer
28. Hoshea
29. Amos
30. Micah
31. Amotz
32. Elijah
33. Elisha
34. Jonah
35. Isaiah
36. Chuldah
37. Joel
38. Nachum
39. Habakkuk
40. Tzefaniah
41. Uriah
42. Jeremiah
43. Ezekiel
44. Daniel (some count Shemaya instead)
45. Baruch
46. Neriah
47. Seriah
48. Mechasiah
49. Haggai
50. Zechariah
51. Malachi
52. Esther
53. Mordechai Bilshan
54. Unknown
55. Unknown

Comment: Regarding the last two which were left as unknown, a note in Artscroll Megillah 14a2 (note 23) reads, "Rashi concludes by confessing ignorance of the identity of the remaining two prophets. Turei Even suggests Elazar ben Aharon the Kohen and Elihu ben Berachel the Buzite. The Vilna Gaon, however, maintains that the missing two are Oded the Prophet and Chanani the Seer. See also Rabbeinu Chananel." Hope this helps

Comment: @AaronLevian Thanks. Oded and Chanani certainly make sense as they are called a Navi in the pesukim in Divrei Hayamim ([2:15:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b15.htm#8) and [2:28:9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b28.htm#9) as well as [2:16:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b16.htm#7) respectively).

Comment: 1200000 OR 120000 (1m OR 120K)

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi The number of Jews counted in the census immediately following the Exodus (recorded in [Numbers 2:32](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0402.htm#32)) is 603550, so twice that is 1207100.

Comment: +1. But note there's some dispute over some on _Rashi_'s list.

Comment: 1,200,000 is only twice the number of the men over 20. Are you assuming there were no/insignificant additional prophetesses?

Comment: @Loewian http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17646/759

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38277&st=&pgnum=80

Comment: Interesting that Daniel made the list, since Megillah 3a says explicitly that he’s not a Navi. Then again, 15a says explicitly that he is a Navi...

Answer (score 4):

*Guide for the Perplexed* [Chapter 45](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp132.htm) is very relevant to this. You should read the entire chapter to get the full idea, but essentially [Maimonides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) says that there are various levels of prophecy, not all of which qualify the recipient as an official prophet. Additionally, one can move between levels – at one point he can be in one category but he can then move up or move down. Thus, there is no real way to give a definitive number of prophets.

Some of the full-fledged prophets named by Maimonides there are:

- Abraham
- Jacob
- Isaiah
- Jeremiah
- Nathan
- Ahijah the Shilonite

Some of those mentioned explicitly as not being full-fledged prophets are:

- David
- Solomon
- Daniel
- Yahaziel the son of Zechariah
- Zechariah the son of Jeoiada the priest
- Azariah son of Oded
- Balaam
- The Judges
- The 70 Elders
- Eldad
- Medad