# Who saw angels?

Tags: tanach, historical-figures, malach-angel, nevua-prophecy, dream

Which historical figures in Tanach had visions of *malachim* (angels)? Which of these were themselves prophets (e.g. Abraham, Jacob, Balaam)? Which were figures very close to prophets but not themselves prophets (e.g. Hagar, Lot)? Were there any such figures who had no connection to either prophets or prophecy?

Similarly, which figures were spoken to by G-d in a dream and what was the corresponding categorical breakdown regarding their connection to actual prophecy?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22946/501

Comment: Eishet Manoach. Lavan. Avimelekh.