Why isn’t Hagar counted as a prophetess?
G-d appears and speaks to her through malochim in Genesis 16 & 21. Has G-d ever interacted with a woman in two separate episodes except her? Notably too she is the first in the written Torah who has angels appear to her.
She’s the only one to give a name to G-d. Except if you count e.g Avraham Avinu in Gen. 21:33 or Yaakov Avinu in 33:20, similarly Moshe Rabbeinu in Exo. 17:15, but even then she retains the distinction of naming G-d in the face of His angels.
It is intersting Sarah is counted as a prophetess but the Rabbis imply her encounter with the divine was less, shall we say, enthusiastic, than Hagar’s.

“She called the name of the Lord Who spoke to her: You are the God who sees me” — Rabbi Yehuda bar Simon and Rabbi Yoḥanan in the name of Rabbi Elazar bar Shimon: The Holy One blessed be He never deigned to speak with a woman except for that righteous woman [Sarah], and that, too, was out of necessity.
Rabbi Abba said in the name of Rabbi Beiri: See how much He spoke in a roundabout manner with her: “No, but you did laugh” (Genesis 18:15). But is it not written [here]: “She called the name of the Lord who spoke to her”?


— Bereshit Rabbah


similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65069/759

Asking a similar question about Daniel: "How can we reconcile the Gemara saying that Daniel was NOT a Navi, with all the Obvious (Very Intense) Prophecies of Daniel written in Sefer Daniel?"

You answer it in the question - whereas Hashem directly conversed with Sarah he only spoke to her through an angel.

There are different approaches to this. The Rambam takes the following (MN 2:42):

וממה שהקדמנוהו מצורך ההזמנה לנבואה, וממה שזכרנו בשתוף שם ׳מלאך׳ תדע
ש׳הגר המצרית׳ אינה נביאה, ולא ׳מנוח ואשתו׳ נביאים – כי זה הדיבור אשר
שמעוהו או שעלה בדעתם, הוא כדמות ׳בת קול׳ אשר יזכרוה ה׳חכמים׳ תמיד,
והוא ענין אחד ילוה לאיש שאינו מזומן, ואמנם יטעה בזה שיתוף השם; והוא
העיקר הדוחה רוב הספקות אשר ב׳תורה׳.
From what we have set forth before regarding the necessity of
preparation for prophecy and from what we have mentioned regarding the
equivocality of the term angel [malakh], you should know that Hagar the
Egyptian was not a prophetess and that Manoah and his wife were no
prophets. For the words that they heard or that occurred to their mind
were similar to the voices [bath-qol], which the Sages
constantly mention. This is a state that accompanies an individual who
is not prepared for prophecy. It is only the equivocality of the term
that occasions errors as to this - this being the principle that
removes most of the difficulties found in the Torah.

He asserts that the term מלאך [malakh] can be used homonymously to indicate different meanings. In this case Hagar is apprehending a bath-qol, which the Torah refers here to as a מלאך.
