# Can Prophecy Exist Outside The Land Of Israel

Tags: nevua-prophecy, golus-exile, daniel-book-of

How could Prophet Daniel have done prophecy for the Persian kings, in exile, because I heard prophets of Israel could only do prophecy in the land of Israel

Answer (score 3):

Daniel is in Kesuvim because it is not prophecy. There is a machlokes as to whether Daniel was or was not a prophet. However, we see that Baruch ben Neriyah (Yirmiyahu's student) never became a prophet because he went into exile *before* he became one (Yirmiyaho 45:3). We also see that Yechezkel (chapter 24) was given when he was already in Bavel.

The point is that a person could only be appointed a prophet in Eretz Yisrael (Yona), but that once he has been established as a prophet (Yechezkel) he can be given the information to tell the other people.

Whether or not Daniel was a prophet, the information that he gave *Nevuchadnetzar* was via *Ruach Hakodesh* which is a lower lever of interaction with *Hashem* than *nevuah* (prophesy).

[Why Isn’t the Book of Daniel Part of the Prophets?](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1735365/jewish/Why-Isnt-the-Book-of-Daniel-Part-of-the-Prophets.htm)

> On the one hand, the Talmud does explicitly state that Daniel was not
>   a prophet.1 On the other hand, when the Talmud states that only “48
>   prophets and 7 prophetesses prophesied to Israel,”2 the sages disagree
>   as to whether Daniel is included in that list or not.3
>
> What is even stranger is that the remark in the Talmud that Daniel was
>   not a prophet is made in connection with an incident in which Daniel
>   seems to have seen a vision, when the three official prophets who were
>   with him did not: [4]
>
> **Footnotes**
>
> [1].Talmud, Megillah 3a.
>
> [2]. Ibid., 14a. It should be noted that when the Talmud states that
>   only 55 prophets “prophesied to Israel,” it does not mean that there
>   were only 55 prophets. In fact, the Talmud there tells us that the
>   number of prophets throughout Jewish history was double the number of
>   people who left Egypt. What it means to say is that there were 55
>   prophets who said prophecies that have relevance for future
>   generations and not just for their own generation.
>
> [3]. See Halachot Gedolot, ch. 76; Seder Olam Rabbah, ch. 20;
>   commentary of Rabbi Shlomo Yitzchaki, Rashi to Megillah, ibid.
>
> [4]. Daniel 10:7.
>
> Those who have ruach ha-kodesh, however, feel as if the divine spirit
>   came upon them. With it they receive a new power that encourages them
>   either to take a specific action, speak wisdom, compose hymns, exhort
>   their fellow men or discuss political or theological problems. All
>   this is done while the one with ruach ha-kodesh is in full possession
>   of his or her senses.10

The experience of Ruach Hakodesh is different from that of nevuah and is on a different level.

> It is true that the inspiration may sometimes come in the form of a
>   dream, as it does with prophets. There is, however, a difference
>   between the visions experienced by prophets in a dream and those that
>   come through ruach ha-kodesh, as was the case with Daniel.
>
> The difference can be seen in how prophets and those inspired by ruach
>   ha-kodesh refer to their visions and dreams. When prophets prophesy,
>   they are informed that the vision was a prophecy, and upon awaking,
>   they state decidedly that it was a prophetic experience

Comment: Since when was Barukh ben Neryah not a prophet?? Rashi lists him as #45 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22949/759

Comment: Just a note: The Rambam (Yesodei Hatorah, 7:2) actually uses Daniel (10:8) "My appearance was horribly changed and I retained no strength" as a proof that one loses control of their senses during prophesy.

Comment: @DoubleAA Rambam in Moreh Nevuchim says that Barukh ben Neriyah tried to attain prophesy, but was unable.

Comment: @user6618 Cool. We'll call it a machloket then.

Comment: @user6618  Megilla 14b lists Baruch and his father as two of the 8 kohanim descended from Rachav who were neviim. Yirmiyaho 45:3 says Baruch complained about not being chosen a navi Rashi, targum Yonasan, Mrchilta at end of Bo

Comment: What about Moshe? He never was in Israel?

Comment: @AlexanderMermelstein The prophets before Matan Torah were different. They were before Eretz Yisrael was given to Bnai Yisrael.

Answer (score -3):

Noah was a prophet. Noah did not live in Eretz Yisrael. QED.

If you want after entry into the land, go with Ezekiel on the banks of the Euphrates.

Comment: Re Noah: Sourcing either of your two premises would make your conclusion more believable. As it is it's hard to tell if this argument is just valid or also sound.

Comment: The Talmud explains the Ezekiel was able to prophesy outside Israel only because he had started to prophesy in Israel before leaving. See Bavli Moed Kattan 25a. I commend you for catching that single "exception".