# Does Judaism recognize prophets/prophecy outside of Israel?

Tags: gentiles, nevua-prophecy

An [answer here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17729/759) says:

> The Tosefta (Sotah 13:4) states:
>
> > משמתו נביאים האחרונים חגי זכריה ומלאכי פסקה רוח הקודש מישראל
> >
> > Once the last prophets -- Haggai, Zechariah and Malachi -- died, the prophetic spirit ceased in Israel.

Does Judaism recognize prophets and prophecy claims from other faiths and religions outside of Eretz Israel as valid?

(This may be considered a duplicate but the crux of the question is in regard to the claims of faiths/religions other than Judaism which I wasn't able to find.)

Comment: You’re asking specifically post-Chagai Zechariah and Malachi, or non-Jewish prophets in general?

Comment: @DonielF - Before, during and after the latter Jewish prophets specifically non-Jewish prophets. I'll reword the question if necessary.

Comment: If before, Bilaam for sure right?

Comment: similar? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69869/759

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857/9682

Comment: Also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33467/9682

Comment: Are these prophets saying things that contradict Judaism? For example, the commandments in the Torah are no longer relevant or idol worship is okay. If so, we would deem the prophet a false prophet.

Comment: There is an opinion wether Maimonides considered Aristotle a prophet, but this is debatable.

Answer (score 2):

The Talmud [[Bava Batra 15b]](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.15b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) names seven prophets who prophesied to non-Jews: Balaam, Balaam's father (Beor), Job, and Job's four friends.

The Midrash says that Balaam was greater than Moses in many respects [Numbers Rabbah 14:20]:

> [The Torah says:] And there has not arisen since, in Israel, a prophet [like Moses] [Deut. 34:10]. In Israel there had not arisen one like him, but there had arisen one like him among the nations of the world. This was in order that the nations of the world might have no excuse for saying: If we had possessed a prophet like Moses, we would have worshipped the Holy One, blessed be He.  What prophet did they have that was like Moses? Balaam the son of Beor. There was a difference, however, between the prophecy of Moses and that of Balaam...
>
> -Moses did not know who was speaking with him, while Balaam knew...
>
> -Moses did not know when the Holy One, blessed be He, would speak with him, while Balaam knew…
>
> -Moses did not know what the Holy One, blessed be He, would speak to him about, while Balaam knew…
>
> -Moses could not speak with [God] whenever he pleased, but Balaam could…

Also:

> -Balaam knew the exact time of God's anger. [Avoda Zar. 4a–b; Sanh. 105b] [Berachot 7a]

Answer (score -3):

“It ceases in Israel” as referring to the Israelite nation. To wit, Yonah is buried in present day Iraq, and Yechezkel is in Iran/Persia. Also don’t forget non-Jewish prophets like Bilaam, who didn’t live in Israel. The list can go on.

Comment: Yonah and Yechezkel both lived before Chagai Zechariah and Malachi.

Comment: My point is that they lived outside of Eretz Yisrael. And prophecy existed among non-Jews as well.