# Have there ever been women prophetesses in the history of Judaism?

Tags: women, navi-prophets

Male prophets are well known - people like Ezekiel and Jeremiah. Who are the women that are normally considered prophets in Judaism and where is the best place to learn about them?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22946/759