# Are there two or more prophets who have the same name?

Tags: names, tanach, navi-prophets

Are there any examples of two different prophets who have the same name?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22949/759

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophets_in_Judaism#The_49_prophets

Comment: Definitely two Zechariahs

Comment: @riki I think he's referring to Zechariah, the Kohen-Navi who was killed preceding the first Temple's destruction, and Zechariah, the prophet who has a Sefer in Trei Asar named for him, who was a member of the Anshei Knesses HaGedolah.

Comment: @Doniel Rambam writes the former wasn't a full Navi, whatever that means. See Alex's answer at my link

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand that there are conflicting opinions there, but there are certainly Rishonim who understand the former was a full Navi.

Comment: @Doniel whatever that means.

Answer (score 5):

Hoshea ben Nun (later changed to Yehoshua) and Hoshea ben Beeri were both prophets who had the same name

Comment: +1 I like this. I'm not sure the op would disqualify based on this, but do we have reason to believe he was a Navi while he was still Hoshea?

Comment: @user depends what you mean by "still" but he sang haazinu as hoshea

Comment: @Double I'm not sure what you mean by him singing haazinu. And his name would've been changed at the beginning of the stay in the midbar, not the end.

Comment: @user וַיָּבֹ֣א מֹשֶׁ֗ה וַיְדַבֵּ֛ר אֶת־כׇּל־דִּבְרֵ֥י הַשִּׁירָֽה־הַזֹּ֖את בְּאׇזְנֵ֣י הָעָ֑ם ה֖וּא וְהוֹשֵׁ֥עַ בִּן־נֽוּן׃

Comment: @Double Gotcha. Was he actually still called that at that point according to Rashi there? He seems to have had an interesting name change as he was referred to as Yehoshua before the change and Hoshea afterwords.

Comment: @user there's no way to know. For all we know everyone called him Hoshea his whole life except Moshe and the Navi recorded it as Yehoshua as a mark of respect to Moshe or something like that. Tanakh is replete with different name versions for people and it's impossible to tell who actually called whom what (יהוסף ישחק רעואל צדקיהו ירובעל etc)

Comment: @Double true [15]

Answer (score 3):

The Talmud [Megillah 14a] says that the number of prophets in Israel was twice the number of Israelites who left Egypt. If you count only the men, that's 1.2 million.  If you count everybody that's 6-8 million.

There aren't that many Jewish names.  Therefore, it is overwhelmingly likely that at least two prophets had the same name.

(The Talmud adds that Tanach recorded only the prophecies of 48 prophets and 7 prophetesses, because only these prophecies had value for future generations.  The other prophecies are not pertinent to us. For a list of these 55, see [here](http://www.jewfaq.org/prophet.htm).  No two have the same name.)