# Why didn't Rivka summon Yaakov?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-toldot, imahot-matriarch-mothers, vayeitzei

Rivka told Yaakov to remain at the home of Lavan until she summoned him ([Bereishis 27:45](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8222#v=45)).  However, we never find that Rivka sent for him, and Yaakov ended up leaving at Hashem's instruction ([Bereishis 31:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8226#v=3)).

Why didn't she?

Comment: If God tells you to jump, you ***don't*** ask "how high?" ....you jump. ;-) .....point being, so Rivkah *didn't* send for Yaakov....but God told him to go, so he went.

Comment: @Shokhet That would be a great answer to "why did Yaakov go if Rivka didn't call him yet" but that wasn't what I asked.

Comment: ....but maybe she didn't call him because God called him first.

Comment: @Shokhet It's possible.  She was a nevia and all - did she not know if she would call him or not?

Comment: I dunno how nevuah works. Maybe she did, maybe she didn't....though I was kind of under the impression that nevuah =/= omniscience. But again, I have no idea how nevuah works.

Comment: @YeZ How do you know she was a Neviah?

Comment: @DoubleAA Beginning of Toldot, Hashem talks to her.

Comment: @Scimonster Most commentators understand God sent her a prophet to tell her that. She is specifically not mentioned in the list of 7 prophetesses.

Comment: @DoubleAA And some say that she also found out about Yitzchak giving Eisav the Brachot through ruach hakodesh.

Comment: @Scimonster Yes. [The fact is she isn't mentioned on the list even though Pshat makes her more likely to be a Neviah than everyone on the list (except Chulda and Devora).](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17646/were-there-more-than-seven-prophetesses#comment40723_17668)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually Rivka did send Devora to call Yaakov, however she died on the way.

[Rashi Braishis 35:8 in the name of Rabbi Moshe Hadarshan](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=452)

> "מה עניין דבורה בבית יעקב? אלא לפי שאמרה רבקה ליעקב (כ"ז, מה) 'ושלחתי
>   ולקחתיך משם' – שלחה דבורה אצלו לפדן ארם לצאת משם, ומתה בדרך".

See also [Medrash Agada](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33177&st=&pgnum=9&hilite=).

Answer (score 3):

Note that besides answering the question, I also deal with the suggestion that Devorah was carrying the message as @GershonGold says in his answer..

Rav Hirsch points out in 35:8 that we do not know that Rivkah had sent Devorah to Yaakov with a message. Note that those who say Rivkah married Yitzchak at age 3, would imply that she had accompanied Rivkah to Yitzchak. Those who say it was at age 14 would allow for her having been in the house of Lavan all those years may have also raised Rachel and Leah and now wanted to go see the child she whose wet-nurse she had been.

> How this old lady, who in any case must have been very advanced in
>   years, found herself in Jacob's company, is not told. Whether she, as
>   some suppose, had  been sent by Rivkah with a message, or had gone
>   with him from Lavan's house as Ramban (Nachmanides) suggests, are only
>   suggestions.

**However** as we see from the beginning of Vayishlach, Yaakov suspected (and with good reason as the meforshim point out) that Eisav had **not** forgiven him for his trickery. Rivkah had said that she would send a message once Eisav was no longer angry and had forgotten what had happened (Toldos 27:45). We see that this had not happened, so she would not have been able to send for him before she died (at age 133 according to some meforshim).