# The number 7,what is the number seven?

Tags: number

Seven days days in a week,7 years, 70 years.
The number 7 seems to complete many things in history and in the calender.

What is so important with the number 7?
WHy is number 7?
Why is so many things completed by the number 7?

I would guess some Rabbis have an deeper understanding of this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shiv'a - mi yodeya?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/507/shiva-mi-yodeya)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a dupe. I sense that the OP isn't seeking a list, but rather why specifically number 7 was chosen for so many things vs. choosing some other number. E.g. why 7 days in the week and not 6 or 8?

Comment: @DanF Perfect comment

Comment: More specific: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34013

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/closing-as-duplicate-of-broader-post#comment12280_3509

Comment: @msh This seems to be asking for a general understanding of what is behind 7 which would include the number of days of Pesach and Succos as a subset.

Comment: Somehow significant to the six days of Creation and the first Shabbos?

Comment: See this, where I describe a symbology for 6, 7 (and the 7th), and 8 based on the Maharal and R' Hirsch
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69608/1570

Answer (score 4):

This question is not asking for a list (as in [Shiv'a - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/507/shiva-mi-yodeya)) but rather what is the basic significance to the number 7 that would cause it to be chosen for so many things. *Ramban* (Nachmanides) says that this is based on the 6+1 (7) days of creation which includes Shabbat. That is, 7 shows the completion of the physical universe and of nature. That is also why the bris (as one example) is on the eighth day as showing that one is going above and beyond the physical universe.

I have seen references to the seven physical dimensions that define the universe, six of space and one of time.

```
1. forward
2. back
3. right
4. left
5. up
6. down
7. time - connects the other six and allows movement or change (ruach)
```

Note that within the universe time only goes in one direction. Once something has happened we cannot travel back as we can with the spacial elements. Memory is what allows a human being to connect to the past, but "times arrow" flies in one "direction" only. As I said, the seventh element is shown by Shabbat which completes the universe and allows all the previous (physical) elements to continue to exist.

Some use ruach of neshama as the seventh connecting element. They also use the Maharal's concept that the six are the elements of space (physicality) and that the seventh (symbolised by Shabbat) is the central (spiritual) element that connects them all and allows them to interact. One can see that given a solid shape, such as a cube or a sphere, one can put only six of those objects around it (of the same size) and still allow them all to touch the center and be connected.

Each of the items that use the number seven within Judaism continues from this consideration to show connection to creation and would have a separate analysis extending from this basic concept.

Comment: Why do the 3 space dimensions get both directions, but time only gets one?

Comment: @DoubleAA Inside the Universe time only goes in one direction. We can only travel ahead and not back. I will also add another comment about it.

Comment: Excellent answer,right on brother! But 7 is also seen as judgment,is this false?

Comment: @Eagel Since I had not seen that, I do not know. try google

Comment: According to the Maharal, the 7th is the hidden middle, in contrast to the 6 sides. And as a hidden essence, it is the spiritual inherent in this world. In contrast to 8, which is reaching beyond this world.

Comment: @MichaBerger Interesting,but how is one to understand that in everyday life,ok,the shabbat speaks of some hidden world?Or Olam haba.How is one to understand number 7 or use it or to think about it?How is knowing about 7 good for us,can you give an example? Hope this is not to complicated or unclear.

Comment: Shabbos is about finding the spiritual in the real world, the one we live in now. It's a time to contemplate how the soul did last week, and to be inspired to do even better the next one. Shabbos is not a day to do, it's a day to find meaning in what one does. As the good books says, "Six days you shall work and accomplish all your creative deeds, and on the seventh day you rest for Hashem your G-d..."

Comment: @MichaBerger Ok,but last comment/question.Does this have anything to do with the Stars or planets,sun or moon? Is this important for the number 7?Or hidden world?

Comment: @Eagel You are asking me to conjecture. The Maharal just associates it with the symbolism that would come naturally to humans living in 3D space. As for visible planets, likely yes. It's non-coincidental that there is a planet Shabtai (Saturn) which is not only associated with Shabbos in rabbinic culture, but also Saturn is to Saturday. But I have no idea what that connection might be. (Nor do esoterica interest me. One of the things that draws me to Mussar is the ability to follow it without ever appealing to nor rejecting Qabbalah or Jewish mysticism.)

Answer (score 0):

In chassidus it is 7 teva and 8 lemaala miteva
Elokim is gematria hateva that name of hashem is the one that is involved in the world