# Seven Ushpizot on Sukkot?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, sukkot

In a number of places [online](https://www.geni.com/projects/The-Holy-Shepherds-Ushpizin/8193), I've seen reference made to a teaching from [Menachem Azariah of Fano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_Azariah_da_Fano), or Rama MiPano, about seven female "guests" which visit the Sukkah over Sukkot, in paralel to the seven male "guests" [mentioned](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01778_part_8.html#HtmpReportNum0028_L2) in the Zohar.

> According to the tradition of Medieval Italian kabbalist Menachem
>   Azariah of Fano, the ushpizot are: Sarah, Miriam, Devorah, Chana, Avigail, Chulda, and Esther.

Where can I find this teaching in Menachem Azariah of Fano's writings, and is he the originator of this idea?

Comment: Those are the 7 traditional female prophetesses https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/564/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Correct. Does that, in of itself, explain why they would be visiting on Sukkot?

Comment: Not at all, as far as I can see. (But on the other hand I have no idea why anybody would visit me on Sukkot.) The exact match of the lists though seems unlikely to be an accident

Comment: I vote "I doubt you" on this *tradition*.

Comment: FWIW, someone on [this site](http://www.hamichlol.org.il/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9C:%D7%94%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA%3F/%D7%94%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%AA_%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%99_%22%D7%94%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA%3F%22/%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D#.D7.90.D7.95.D7.A9.D7.A4.D7.99.D7.96.D7.95.D7.AA) suggests that actually, he just aligned the 7 prophetesses with the seven sephirot, and after the ushpizin became equated with the sephirot, his statement transformed to say that the prophetesses are the ushpizot.

Comment: [cont.] While not mentioning Rama of Fano, R. Shalom of Belz is quoted there as stating the "the imahot" come to the succah.