# Sha’arei HaKedushah on Middos

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books

The Sha’arei HaKedushah writes, *"One must exert greater caution in exercising proper middos than in observance of the mitzvos."*

Does anyone know where the Sha’arei HaKedushah says this?

Answer (score 2):

This is found in [*Sha'arei K'dusha* 1:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%91):

> והנה ענין המידות הן מוטבעות באדם בנפש השפלה הנקראת "יסודית", הכלולה מארבע בחינות, הדומם והצומחת והבהמית והמדברת. כי גם הן מורכבות מטוב ורע, והנה בנפש הזה תלויות המידות הטובות והרעות, והן כסא ויסוד ושורש אל הנפש העליונה השכלית, אשר בה תלויין תרי"ג מצות התורה כנזכר לעיל בשער ראשון. ולפיכך אין המידות מכלל התרי"ג מצות, ואמנם הן הכנות עקריות אל תרי"ג המצות בקיומן או בביטולם, יען כי אין כח בנפש השכלית לקיים המצות על ידי תרי"ג איברי הגוף אלא באמצעות נפש היסודית, המחוברת אל הגוף עצמו, בסוד (ויקרא יז יד): "כי נפש כל בשר דמ"ו בנפשו הוא", ולפיכך ענין המידות הרעות קשים מן העברות עצמן מאד מאד.
>
> ובזה תבין ענין מה שאמרו רבותינו ז"ל (שבת דף ק"ה ע"ב), כל הכועס כאלו עובד עבודה זרה ממש שהיא היותר שקולה ככל תרי"ג המצות, וכן אמרו (סוטה דף ע"א) מי שיש בו גסות הרוח הוא ככופר בעיקר וראוי לגדעו כאשירה ואין עפרו ננער וכו' וכאלה רבות. והבן זה מאד, כי להיותם עקרים ויסודות לא נמנו בכלל תרי"ג המצות התלויות בנפש השכלית, **ונמצא כי יותר צריך ליזהר ממדות הרעות יותר מן קיום המצות עשה ולא תעשה** כי בהיותו בעל מדות טובות בנקל יקיים כל המצות:

Translation:

> The idea behind *middos* (character traits) is that they are ingrained in the basest level of a person's soul that is called "foundational." This comprises [four aspects](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16090): inanimate, growing, animal, and speaking. For these are also composed of good and bad, and they are a seat, foundation, and root for the rational, lofty soul, upon which the 613 commandments of the Torah are dependent, as mentioned above in chapter one.
>
> Therefore, the *middos* are not included among the 613 commandments, though they, by their attainment or negation, are essential prerequisites for the 613 commandments, since the rational soul is unable to fulfill the commandments via the [corresponding 613 parts of the body](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10406) except through the medium of the foundational soul that is connected to the body itself. This is the hidden meaning of, "As for the soul of all flesh, its blood ("דמ"ו") is in its soul" ([*Vayikra* 17:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0317.htm#14)). Therefore, bad *middos* are much worse than the sins themselves.
>
> Through this, you can understand the idea behind what our Rabbis of blessed memory said ([*Shabbos* 105b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=105b&format=text)),<sup>1</sup> "Whoever becomes angry is as if he worships *avoda zara* ('idolatry' or 'foreign worship')" itself, which is weighed so heavily that is equivalent to all 613 commandments. And they have likewise stated ([*Sotah* 5a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=5&format=text)), "Whoever is haughty" is as if he denies the fundamentals of faith, and "it is fitting to cut him down like an *asheira*...<sup>2</sup> and his dust will not stir [at the time of the resurrection of the dead]," etc. And there are many examples like these.
>
> Understand this well, for since they are essentials and foundations, they are not enumerated among the 613 commandments that depend on the rational soul. **And it emerges that one must be more vigilant in the avoidance of bad *middos* than in the fulfillment of the positive and negative commandments**, for he will easily be able to fulfill all the commandments by being a master of good *middos*.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>While this concept can be traced to the *gemara* in *Shabbos*, this particular quote is found in the Rambam ([*Hil. Dei'os* 2:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=2&perek=2&halocha=3)).</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>See [*D'varim* 7:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0507.htm#5), "And hew down their *Asherim*..."</sub>