# Belief in Yechidah

Tags: sources-mekorot, theology, mysticism-kabbalah, soul

According to [Chabad.org,](http://beta.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3194/jewish/What-is-a-Soul.htm)

> Yechidah connotes the essence of the soul--its unity with its source,
>   the singular essence of G-d. For the essence of the soul of man is
>   "literally a part of G-d above"3--a piece of G-d in us, so to speak.

Did Jews in the first century or even before that have consciousness of Yechidah or is it a belief which developed in Talmudic times? Is there any place where this is mentioned in the Tanakh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Yechida* is one of [five levels of the soul](http://beta.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380651/jewish/Levels-of-Soul-Consciousness.htm) often described in the teachings of Chassidus, which were only revealed about 250 years ago - which is likely when the concept (named as such) became mainstream. The soul's five names are mentioned in Midrash Rabba ([Bereishis 14:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&pgnum=37), [Devorim 2:26](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14384&pgnum=175)), [written in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_Rabbah#Date) the 4th - 5th century - the earliest source I could find. Although not explicitly mentioned in Tanach, it is [connected](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaam/tshu/4/45d/45d) with a verse in Psalms (22:21):

> הצילה מחרב נפשי מיד כלב יחידתי
>
> Save my soul from the sword, my "Yechida" from the grip of the dog.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe explains in [Kuntres Inyona Shel Toras Hachasidus](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/inyono/12.htm) (in English "[On the Essence of Chassidus](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15630&pgnum=66)") that the five levels of the soul correspond with the five levels in Torah: Peshat, Remez, Drush, Sod and Chassidus. Thus, on one occasion the Zohar does not even list Yechida when enumerating the levels of the soul, and the Midrash just brings it in passing. It is specifically in the teaching of Chassidus that the concept is explained.

Comment: In the Midrash, they are not described as levels, but names.

Comment: @Menachem True, but different names for the same things is indicative of different qualities.

Comment: This concept was stated earlier than 250 years ago. The Alshich (16 century) wrote that these are different aspects/parts of the soul, not merely different names for the soul (Commentary to B'reishis 43:34).

Comment: [Pardes](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14750/759)ach? When did Chassidus get added to the list?

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed, the linked discource discusses the fifth dimension of Torah in length - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasidic_philosophy#Philosophical_explanation) has quite a good summary.

Comment: @DoubleAA Chassidus isnt added to Pardes in the simple since. When connecting the 4 levels of Torah to the Soul, you are missing a connection to Yechidah. Since Yechidah is the essence of the soul, it is a composite in a sense of all the 4 soul faculties below. Chassidus is connected to Yechida as explained in the sicha quoted above, because it is NOT a 5th level. Chassidus takes the 4 levels of Torah and shows the deep connection between those levels and reveals a person can serve Hashem even from the most seemingly "abstract" Torah concept.

Comment: @Michoel it is also discussed in Derech Hashem, and mentioned in the Zohar. Chassidus is probably the first to explain it in a way that makes sense to the general public, but the ideas predate the revelation of Chassidus of course.

Comment: @DoubleAA FWIW, this is also the first time I heard that Chassidus is a 5th dimension, generally I heard it is the second facet of Sod, i.e. the personal and private secrets to the Torah, rather than the "mystical" secrets