# 5 "parts" of the nefesh- What is the Rambam's source?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, pirke-avot-ethicsof, soul

In his introduction to Avos (Shmomneh P'rakim), the Rambam delineates 5 "parts" of the human nefesh. Is this something that he came to on his own or does he have a source for this?

I know that the Rambam was well versed in both ancient and what was then contemporary philosophy and that it's very likely that this idea came from one of those sources. However, the bit of research I did on this did not turn anything up on this specific point.

Comment: see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20599

Answer (score 1):

Is already mentioned in Medrash Rabba בראשית רבה יד citing that in the entire Tana"ch the Torah calls the soul in five different ways.

חמישה שמות נקראו לה: נפש, רוח, נשמה, חיה, יחידה:

נפש - זה הדם, שנאמר (דברים יב כג): "כי הדם הוא הנפש".
רוח - שהיא עולה ויורדת, שנאמר (קהלת ג כא): "מי יודע רוח בני האדם העולה היא למעלה [ורוח הבהמה היורדת היא למטה לארץ]".
נשמה - זו האופיא. דברייתא אמרין: האופיתא טבא.
חיה (תהלים קמג ג, איוב לג כח) - שכל האיברים מתים, והיא חיה בגוף.
יחידה (תהלים כב כא, תהלים לה יז) - שכל האיברים משניים שניים, והיא יחידה בגוף.

Comment: Is that really where the Rambam gets this idea from? Five names is different from five parts. Plus Rambam isn't known for taking Aggadic Midrashim like this all that literally.

Comment: @DoubleAA  The Rambam definitely saw Midrashim and I'm not sure if its reasonable to make a blanket statement about what he used for his sources vs what he didn't.

Comment: @Trust Good thing I didn't say he didn't see Midrashim nor did I make any blanket statements about what he used as sources.