# Is it a popular notion that a Jew should "have at least three children..."?

Tags: number, family-members, pregnancy-birth, provenance, holocaust-shoah

I have heard it said, "Every Jew must have at least three children (though more is preferable).  Two to replace the parents when they die, and at least one more to make up for those lost in the Shoah."

I thought only my parents said this until I read it in a novel recently.  I know that to "be fruitful and multiply" is an important value, but articulated like this specifically - is it a popular notion?  If so, amongst whom?  What is the origin?

Comment: Do you refer to having more children _specifically_ to counteract the Shoah?

Comment: Yes.  As in, "we have to make up for the would-be children of Jews tragically lost in the Holocaust."

Comment: R' Yehuda Henkin would not give a heter to a couple to use birth control pills regularly until they have two boys and two girls.

Comment: I've heard this only from a friend, but she said it as if it were a common idea.  I have no idea where it came from.

Comment: COMMENT POLL: Upvote this comment if you have heard of the notion before, and....

Comment: Upvote this comment if you have not heard of this notion before.

Answer (score 2):

Yevamot 61b:

Mishnah: One may not desist from reproduction unless he has children. Bais Shamai
say two males, Bais Hillel say one male and one female, as it says (Berashis ch. 5) “He
created them male and female”

Gemorah: Bais Shamai says: two males. What is the reason for Bais Shamai’s position?
We learn from Moshe as it says (Divrai Hayamim 1 ch. 29) “the sons of Moshe: Gershom
and Eliezer.” And the reason for Bais Hillel? We learn from the creation of the world.
Why does Bais Shamai not learn from the creation of the world? We do not learn what is
possible from what is impossible
(Rashi explains the opinion of Bais Shamai that it was impossible to create the world with only two males since they could not reproduce. However, now that there is a large population and no lack of women in the world, the mitzvah could be defined as having two sons)

copied from http://www.hochheimer.net/rabbi_audio/Mitzvas%20Peru%20Urvu%20sources%201.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The Shulhan Arukh itself brings in Even HaEzer 1:5 that a man need only father a son and a daughter, with the caveat that they are both fertile and out live him.  However Rav Haim HaLevy Donin writes in his book To Be a Jew p123 that a person should have four.  However he does note:

> The minimum number of children one must have to fulfill the command is
>   a matter of Rabbinic dispute.

Comment: I would argue that this doesn't really answer the question about whether the idea of having 3 children is a popular notion.

Comment: It's a matter of Rabbinic dispute.  That is an answer.  There are no sources of which I am aware that specifically say three.  I know of two(which is codified in the Sh"A) and have heard an argument for four.

Comment: @RabbiMichaelTzadok What is the reasoning for four (just curious)?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/450/21

Comment: Two to fulfil "pru urvu", and another two to fulfil "uva'erev al tanach yadecha."

Comment: Ummm... that's still just two to fulfill the command. What is the opinion of 4?